# How do I match [Any Character Except X] in a regular expression?

Tags: regex, asp-classic

Is there are way to do this?

So if X is the unwanted character, I'd be looking for something like (.*[^X])

The aim is to match every character in a string until an X turns up.

I've searched high and low, but can't find the answer.

Comment: well, ```"(.*)[^X]"``` should match. So you gave the answer yourself pretty much already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To match everything up to a certain character `X`, the simplest should be;

```
[^X]*
```

[Simple refiddle to show it](http://refiddle.co/gpn).

Answer (score 1):

Another flavour, which is close to what you had in mind originally:

```
(.*?)X
```

Greedy capture `?` is the trick here. You will need to take the first captured group in code if you want to exclude X character from the result.

Comment: it should not include `x` in the result!

Comment: @Anirudh: Hence the brackets. Take the first captured group in code then.