# Replace query parameter with another value/token

Tags: c#, regex, url

I am trying to replace a URL query pattern `wID=xxx`, where `xxx` can be a digit, number or white space, with the query `wID=[[WID]]` (note that the query is case sensitive). I would like to know how can I achieve this. Currently, I am using regex to find the pattern in the URL and replace it using `Regex.Replace()` as follows:

```
private const string Pattern = @"wID=^[0-9A-Za-z ]+$";
private const string Replace = @"wID=[[WID]]";
/// <summary>
/// Extension method to evaluate the url token for wid
/// </summary>
/// <param name="rawUrl">Incoming URL</param>
/// <returns>Expected URL</returns>
public string GetUrl(string rawUrl)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(rawUrl))
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }

    string result = Regex.Replace(rawUrl, Pattern, Replace);
    return result;
}
```

But this isn't giving me the desired output, as the regex pattern is incorrect, I suppose. Any better way to do this?
My question was related to the implementation of regex pattern to find and replace the URL query parameter value, I found the URI builder is more helpful in these cases and can be used rather so it's different question.

Comment: You shouldnt use Regex for this, there are already built in libraries that help you parse URIs.  If you include a sample URL I can provide a regex-less answer

Comment: A sample URL is "https://fod.infobase.com/PortalPlaylists.aspx?xtid=10112&wID=123" The position of wID can be anywhere in the URL

Comment: Do you need the `[` and `]` to be escaped?

Comment: input = "https://fod.infobase.com/PortalPlaylists.aspx?xtid=10112&wID=123" 
output = "https://fod.infobase.com/PortalPlaylists.aspx?xtid=10112&wID=[[WID]]"

Comment: I've seen the URL, I am asking if you want the resulting url to have the `[` and `]` characters escaped?

Comment: nope I don't want escaped

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace item in querystring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772253/replace-item-in-querystring)

Comment: string result = Regex.Replace(rawUrl, "wID=[0-9A-Za-z]*", "wID=[[WID]]"); this worked for me

Answer (score 3):

As @maccettura said, you can use a built in. Here we will use [`HttpUtility.ParseQueryString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150046.aspx)  to parse the parameters then we set the value and finally we replace the query.

[Try it online!](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CfbBFF)

```
public static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine(GetUrl("http://example.org?wID=xxx"));
}

/// <summary>
/// Extension method to evaluate the url token for wid
/// </summary>
/// <param name="rawUrl">Incoming URL</param>
/// <returns>Expected URL</returns>
public static string GetUrl(string rawUrl)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(rawUrl))
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }
    var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(rawUrl);
    var queryString = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uriBuilder.Query);
    queryString.Set("wID", "[[WID]]");
    uriBuilder.Query = queryString.ToString();
    return uriBuilder.Uri.ToString();
}
```

output

```
http://example.org/?wID=[[WID]]
```

Comment: What if you got another query parameter name similiar to 'wID' (e.g. 'qwID')?

Comment: Probably better to `.Remove("wID")` then manually prepend `wID=[[WID]]&`, unfortunately you cannot assign `[[WID]]` directly as it will get escaped.

Answer (score 2):

There are better ways of doing this.
Have a look at parsing the query string using a [NameValueCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.namevaluecollection(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
 var queryStringCollection = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(Request.QueryString.ToString());
 queryStringCollection.Remove("wID");
 string newQuery = $"{queryStringCollection.ToString()}&wID=[[WID]]";
```

Comment: ParseQueryString actually uses a specialized Http collection that will escape [ and ] when you .Set.

Comment: good point @AlexK. I didn't even notice that. I've updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

I will toss my own answer in since its a bit more re-usable and it does *not* escape the brackets (`[]`):

```
public static string ModifyUrlParameters(string rawUrl, string key, string val)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(rawUrl))
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }

    //Builds a URI from your string
    var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(rawUrl);        

    //Gets the query string as a NameValueCollection
    var queryItems = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uriBuilder.Uri.Query);

    //Sets the key with the new val
    queryItems.Set(key, val);

    //Sets the query to the new updated query
    uriBuilder.Query = queryItems.ToString();

    //returns the uri as a string
    return uriBuilder.Uri.ToString();
}
```

An input of: `http://example.org?wID=xxx`

Results in:  `http://example.org/?wID=[[WID]]`

Fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wdPehA)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a Regex for that.

```
var index = rawUrl.IndexOf("wID=");
if (index > -1)
{
   rawUrl = rawUrl.Substring(0, index + 4) + "[[WID]]";
}
```

Comment: This does not seem right.  Why are you starting at the beginning of `rawUrl` for your substring?  Why is it hardcoded to a 4 length?