# How to build a query string for a URL in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, url, query-string

A common task when calling web resources from a code is building a query string to including all the necessary parameters. While by all means no rocket science, there are some nifty details you need to take care of like, appending an `&` if not the first parameter, encoding the parameters etc.

The code to do it is very simple, but a bit tedious:

```
StringBuilder SB = new StringBuilder();
if (NeedsToAddParameter A) 
{ 
  SB.Append("A="); SB.Append(HttpUtility.UrlEncode("TheValueOfA")); 
}

if (NeedsToAddParameter B) 
{
  if (SB.Length>0) SB.Append("&"); 
  SB.Append("B="); SB.Append(HttpUtility.UrlEncode("TheValueOfB")); }
}
```

This is such a common task one would expect a utility class to exist that makes it more elegant and readable. Scanning MSDN, I failed to find one—which brings me to the following question:

What is the most elegant clean way you know of doing the above?

Comment: It's a bit sad that even at the current point in time, there seems to be no _straightforward_ way to deal with querystrings. And by straightforward, I mean an OOB, non-internal, standards-compliant framework class. Or maybe I'm missing out on something?

Comment: You're not missing anything. Querystring building is a major gap in the framework that I've tried to fill with [Flurl](http://tmenier.github.io/Flurl).

Comment: [Personally the technique I use is one that I've referenced in this question:](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26744471/2108310)

Comment: You just got me thinking I should build one.. new UrlBuilder(existing).AddQuery("key", "value").ToString()

Comment: This answer will work for easily nested objects as well [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60936159/9590885)

Answer (score 328, accepted):

If you look under the hood the QueryString property is a NameValueCollection. When I've done similar things I've usually been interested in serialising AND deserialising so my suggestion is to build a NameValueCollection up and then pass to:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Collections.Specialized;

private string ToQueryString(NameValueCollection nvc)
{
    var array = (
        from key in nvc.AllKeys
        from value in nvc.GetValues(key)
            select string.Format(
                "{0}={1}",
                HttpUtility.UrlEncode(key),
                HttpUtility.UrlEncode(value))
        ).ToArray();
    return "?" + string.Join("&", array);
}
```

I imagine there's a super elegant way to do this in LINQ too...

Comment: The HTTP spec (RFC 2616) doesn't say anything about what query strings can contain. Nor does RFC 3986, which defines the generic URI format. The key/value pair format that is commonly used is called `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, and is actually defined by HTML, for the purpose of submitting form data as part of a `GET` request. HTML 5 does not forbid multiple values per key in this format, and in fact it requires that the browser produce multiple values per key in the case that the page (incorrectly) contains multiple fields with the same `name` attribute. See http://goo.gl/uk1Ag

Comment: @annakata: I know my comment is over a year old (and the answer over two years old!), but NameValueCollection very much supports multiple values per key, by using the GetValues(key) method.

Comment: @MauricioScheffer: But NameValueCollection doesn't transform into a querystring "correctly". For example, if you set the QueryString parameter on WebClient where the same key is present multiple times, it turns into "path?key=value1,value2" instead of "path?key=value1&key=value2", which is a common (standard?) pattern.

Comment: @DavidPope : use GetValues(key)

Comment: @MauricioScheffer: I'm not building the querystring, WebClient is. I guess my comment is more about WebClient; slightly offtopic but relevant to the broader discussion.

Comment: @DavidPope : ah, sorry. That does look like a bug in WebClient, I'd file an issue in http://connect.microsoft.com , although I doubt they'll fix it :(

Comment: Regarding multiple values per key, I believe that in HTML, if you have a multi-select list-box with multiple items selected and submitted, they are sent in the multiple value format mentioned by David.

Comment: You might want to use Uri.EscapeDataString instead of HttpUtility.UrlEncode which is more portable. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573290/httputility-urlencode-in-windows-phone-7

Comment: There is no reason to implement your own query builder when one is already available in C# libraries - see the answer by John Bledsoe

Comment: fo mine nvc.GetValues(key) returns the incorrect result when the value contains some special characters, for example, '+'. It cast it to space!

Comment: you have to also include `using System.Linq` to get rid of using Linq errors

Answer (score 864):

You can create a new writeable instance of `HttpValueCollection` by calling `System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty)`, and then use it as any `NameValueCollection`. Once you have added the values you want, you can call `ToString` on the collection to get a query string, as follows:

```
NameValueCollection queryString = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);

queryString.Add("key1", "value1");
queryString.Add("key2", "value2");

return queryString.ToString(); // Returns "key1=value1&key2=value2", all URL-encoded
```

The `HttpValueCollection` is internal and so you cannot directly construct an instance. However, once you obtain an instance you can use it like any other `NameValueCollection`. Since the actual object you are working with is an `HttpValueCollection`, calling ToString method will call the overridden method on `HttpValueCollection`, which formats the collection as a URL-encoded query string.

After searching SO and the web for an answer to a similar issue, this is the most simple solution I could find.

**.NET Core**

If you're working in .NET Core, you can use the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.QueryHelpers` class, which simplifies this greatly.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.webutilities.queryhelpers

Sample Code:

```
const string url = "https://customer-information.azure-api.net/customers/search/taxnbr";
var param = new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "CIKey", "123456789" } };

var newUrl = new Uri(QueryHelpers.AddQueryString(url, param));
```

Comment: You could probably create an extension method called ToURLQueryString for the IDictionary interface: `public static string ToURLQueryString(this IDictionary dict) { ... }`

Comment: This method is not [standard-compliant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Non-standard_implementations) for multibyte characters. It will encode them as %uXXXX instead of %XX%XX. Resulting query strings may be incorrectly interpreted by web servers. This is even documented in internal framework class HttpValueCollection that is returned by HttpUtility.ParseQueryString() . Comment says that they keep this behavior for backward-compatibility reasons.

Comment: Note there is an important difference between HttpUtilityPraseQueryString("") and new NameValueCollection()  -- only the HttpUtility result will override ToString() to produce a proper querystring

Comment: This is the best answer

Comment: GREAT trick! I used this in [Flurl](https://github.com/tmenier/Flurl) and credited you in the source. Thanks!

Comment: What about cases where you want multiple instances of a name in the query string? For example, "type=10&type=21".

Comment: @Finster
You can add multiple instances of a name to the query string using the `Add` method. I.e 
`queryString.Add("type", "1"); 
queryString.Add("type", "2");`

Using the `Add` method is probably a better way of doing this all of the time actually.

Comment: For an example of using the same technique but being able to use a syntax like `query = BuildQueryString(new { param = "value" })` see the answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/36826806/984780

Comment: adding to @FrankSchwieterman & @igaltabachnik - `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString` actually returns the internal `HttpValueCollection`, a subclass of NameValueCollection, which overrides `ToString` and does the encoding there. [code via referencesource.ms.com](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/HttpValueCollection.cs,1b61ed162f050087,references)

Comment: Why you don't use "new NameValueCollection()" at the very first line?

Comment: @Oswald: Because it's not a `NameValueCollection` instance that you need, but an instance of a subclass of that type. And, as is stated below the code: "The HttpValueCollection is internal and so you cannot directly construct an instance."

Comment: It appears the issue mentioned by @alex is fixed as of .NET 5.0 (e,g if you include a chinese character like `是` it is encoded as `%e6%98%af`) so you shouldn't worry about `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString()` not being standards-compliant.

Comment: For the .Net Core QueryHelpers a Dictionary could cause issues as in certain circumstances you may need to pass multiple parameters with the same key, e.g. get a list of books back by book id's you may want ?book=1&book=2 so you may want to use an Enumerable KeyValue Pair instead.

Comment: @Finster please, see my reply about [how to create query parameters with multiple instances of name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77485815/1646240). E.g.: `"type=10&type=21"`

Answer (score 115):

With the inspiration from Roy Tinker's comment, I ended up using a simple extension method on the Uri class that keeps my code concise and clean:

```
using System.Web;

public static class HttpExtensions
{
    public static Uri AddQuery(this Uri uri, string name, string value)
    {
        var httpValueCollection = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uri.Query);

        httpValueCollection.Remove(name);
        httpValueCollection.Add(name, value);

        var ub = new UriBuilder(uri);
        ub.Query = httpValueCollection.ToString();

        return ub.Uri;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Uri url = new Uri("http://localhost/rest/something/browse").
          AddQuery("page", "0").
          AddQuery("pageSize", "200");
```

---

**Edit - Standards compliant variant**

As several people pointed out, `httpValueCollection.ToString()` encodes Unicode characters in a [non-standards-compliant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urlencodeunicode.aspx) way. This is a variant of the same extension method that handles such characters by invoking `HttpUtility.UrlEncode` method instead of the deprecated `HttpUtility.UrlEncodeUnicode` method.

```
using System.Web;

public static Uri AddQuery(this Uri uri, string name, string value)
{
    var httpValueCollection = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uri.Query);

    httpValueCollection.Remove(name);
    httpValueCollection.Add(name, value);

    var ub = new UriBuilder(uri);

    // this code block is taken from httpValueCollection.ToString() method
    // and modified so it encodes strings with HttpUtility.UrlEncode
    if (httpValueCollection.Count == 0)
        ub.Query = String.Empty;
    else
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < httpValueCollection.Count; i++)
        {
            string text = httpValueCollection.GetKey(i);
            {
                text = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(text);

                string val = (text != null) ? (text + "=") : string.Empty;
                string[] vals = httpValueCollection.GetValues(i);

                if (sb.Length > 0)
                    sb.Append('&');

                if (vals == null || vals.Length == 0)
                    sb.Append(val);
                else
                {
                    if (vals.Length == 1)
                    {
                        sb.Append(val);
                        sb.Append(HttpUtility.UrlEncode(vals[0]));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        for (int j = 0; j < vals.Length; j++)
                        {
                            if (j > 0)
                                sb.Append('&');

                            sb.Append(val);
                            sb.Append(HttpUtility.UrlEncode(vals[j]));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        ub.Query = sb.ToString();
    }

    return ub.Uri;
}
```

Comment: You should also URL encode the value. queryString.Add(name, Uri.EscapeDataString(value));

Comment: Check this [line](https://gist.github.com/uhaciogullari/6218878). / is not encoded.

Comment: Thanks for improving this answer.It fixed the problem with multibyte characters.

Comment: In your second solution, surely `httpValueCollection.Count == 0` will never return `true` as it is preceded by `httpValueCollection.Add(name, value)`?

Comment: @dav_i That's because I didn't want to make any changes to the original Microsoft code except the encoding part.

Comment: Side note, this doesn't work with relative urls because you can't instantiate the UriBuilder from a relative Uri.

Comment: @YuriyFaktorovich Gah. I'm wrong again. OperationNotSupported for relative uris. Best I can do is return a new Uri it seems by building it with strings internally.

Comment: Would you mind additionally licensing this under CC0 or something? (also @Andy: please respect CC-BY-SA in your inhouse library)

Comment: @Thomas .NET Core is under MIT license, so this shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: I added a remove key so that a duplicate can't be added.
https://dotnetfiddle.net/hTlyAd

Comment: It's a pity that it requires System.Web which is not available in .Net core.

Comment: @Vedran, why don't use WebUtility instead of HttpUtility form heavy System.Web.dll?

Answer (score 64):

Curious that no one has mentioned QueryBuilder from AspNet.Core.

It's helpful when you have a query with duplicate key like `?filter=a&filter=b`

```
var qb = new QueryBuilder();
qb.Add("filter", new string[] {"A", "B"});
```

Then you'll just add qb to the URI, it is converted automatically to string.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.extensions.querybuilder?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: There are so many answers here, it took a while to find the one that is correct in current times of developing with .NET Core.

Comment: Can't seem to access this in dotnet core 3.1.  The namespace import is not found and attempting to add the nuget package https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/3.1.10 results in a restore error `error: NU1213: The package Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref 3.1.10 has a package type DotnetPlatform that is incompatible with this project. 
error: Package 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref' is incompatible with 'all' frameworks in project`

Comment: I think the package is only available in dotnet 5.

Comment: The package _is_ available in dotnet 3.1 (earlier, too, iirc), but it has the serious drawback of not being `netstandard2.0` compatible, so not useful for my class library.

Comment: This is the *correct* modern solution, (took a while to find). Additionally the class `QueryString` from 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http' namespace can be used: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.querystring.create?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: NB: QueryBuilder requires the [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions/) which has been deprecated and is no longer maintained.

Answer (score 50):

[Flurl](https://flurl.dev/) [disclosure: I'm the author] supports building query strings via anonymous objects (among other ways):

```
var url = "http://www.some-api.com".SetQueryParams(new
{
    api_key = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SomeApiKey"],
    max_results = 20,
    q = "Don't worry, I'll get encoded!"
});
```

The optional Flurl.Http companion lib allows you to do HTTP calls right off the same fluent call chain, extending it into a full-blown REST client:

```
T result = await "https://api.mysite.com"
    .AppendPathSegment("person")
    .SetQueryParams(new { ap_key = "my-key" })
    .WithOAuthBearerToken("MyToken")
    .PostJsonAsync(new { first_name = firstName, last_name = lastName })
    .ReceiveJson<T>();
```

The full package is available on NuGet:

`PM> Install-Package Flurl.Http`

or just the stand-alone URL builder:

`PM> Install-Package Flurl`

Comment: As far as I've tried, this is the solution that can give you the opportunity to add Arrays in your QueryString !!

Answer (score 32):

I answered a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229925/outputing-a-manipulated-querystring-in-c/) a while ago. Basically, the best way would be to use the class **`HttpValueCollection`**, which ASP.NET's `Request.QueryString` property actually is, unfortunately it is internal in the .NET framework.
You could use Reflector to grab it (and place it into your Utils class). This way you could manipulate the query string like a NameValueCollection, but with all the url encoding/decoding issues taken care for you.

`HttpValueCollection` extends `NameValueCollection`, and has a constructor that takes an *encoded* query string (ampersands and question marks included), and it overrides a `ToString()` method to later rebuild the query string from the underlying collection.

Example:

```
  var coll = new HttpValueCollection();

  coll["userId"] = "50";
  coll["paramA"] = "A";
  coll["paramB"] = "B";      

  string query = coll.ToString(true); // true means use urlencode

  Console.WriteLine(query); // prints: userId=50&paramA=A&paramB=B
```

Comment: Thank you... i noticed that the NameValueCollection it returns has a ToString() that acts differently but couldn't figure out why.

Comment: `httpValueCollection.ToString()` actually calls `httpValueCollection.ToString(true)` so adding the `true` explicity is not required.

Comment: HttpValueCollection is an internal class therefore you cannot instantiated it.

Answer (score 31):

Here's a fluent/lambda-ish way as an extension method (combining concepts in previous posts) that supports multiple values for the same key.  My personal preference is extensions over wrappers for discover-ability by other team members for stuff like this.  Note that there's controversy around encoding methods, plenty of posts about it on Stack Overflow (one such [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/602642/server-urlencode-vs-httputility-urlencode)) and MSDN bloggers (like [this one](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/yangxind/archive/2006/11/09/don-t-use-net-system-uri-unescapedatastring-in-url-decoding.aspx)).

```
public static string ToQueryString(this NameValueCollection source)
{
    return String.Join("&", source.AllKeys
        .SelectMany(key => source.GetValues(key)
            .Select(value => String.Format("{0}={1}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(key), HttpUtility.UrlEncode(value))))
        .ToArray());
}
```

**edit:** with null support, though you'll probably need to adapt it for your particular situation

```
public static string ToQueryString(this NameValueCollection source, bool removeEmptyEntries)
{
    return source != null ? String.Join("&", source.AllKeys
        .Where(key => !removeEmptyEntries || source.GetValues(key)
            .Where(value => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            .Any())
        .SelectMany(key => source.GetValues(key)
            .Where(value => !removeEmptyEntries || !String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            .Select(value => String.Format("{0}={1}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(key), value != null ? HttpUtility.UrlEncode(value) : string.Empty)))
        .ToArray())
        : string.Empty;
}
```

Comment: This fails if any of the values are null

Comment: this is wrong it generate many query strings for each key value pair

Comment: @GayanRanasinghe: What does that even mean?

Answer (score 25):

Here's my late entry.  I didn't like any of the others for various reasons, so I wrote my own.

This version features:

- Use of StringBuilder only.  No ToArray() calls or other extension methods.  It doesn't look as pretty as some of the other responses, but I consider this a core function so efficiency is more important than having "fluent", "one-liner" code which hide inefficiencies.
- Handles multiple values per key. (Didn't need it myself but just to silence Mauricio ;)

  ```
  public string ToQueryString(NameValueCollection nvc)
  {
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("?");

      bool first = true;

      foreach (string key in nvc.AllKeys)
      {
          foreach (string value in nvc.GetValues(key))
          {
              if (!first)
              {
                  sb.Append("&");
              }

              sb.AppendFormat("{0}={1}", Uri.EscapeDataString(key), Uri.EscapeDataString(value));

              first = false;
          }
      }

      return sb.ToString();
  }
  ```

### Example Usage

```
        var queryParams = new NameValueCollection()
        {
            { "x", "1" },
            { "y", "2" },
            { "foo", "bar" },
            { "foo", "baz" },
            { "special chars", "? = &" },
        };

        string url = "http://example.com/stuff" + ToQueryString(queryParams);

        Console.WriteLine(url);
```

### Output

```
http://example.com/stuff?x=1&y=2&foo=bar&foo=baz&special%20chars=%3F%20%3D%20%26
```

Comment: I like that this doesn't use HttpUtility which is under System.Web and not available everywhere.

Comment: +1 for not using linq and not using HttpUtility. I'd create an empty sb and ditch the "bool first" variable and then in the loop simply have sb.Append(sb.Length == 0 ? "?" : "&") before the sb.AppendFormat(). Now if nvc is empty the method will return an empty string instead of a lonely "?".

Comment: This answer handles single parameters with multiple values. eg ?id=1&id=3&id=2&id=9

Answer (score 23):

I needed to solve the same problem for a portable class library (PCL) that I'm working on.  In this case, I don't have access to System.Web so I can't use ParseQueryString.

Instead I used `System.Net.Http.FormUrlEncodedContent` like so:

```
var url = new UriBuilder("http://example.com");

url.Query = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new Dictionary<string,string>()
{
    {"param1", "val1"},
    {"param2", "val2"},
    {"param3", "val3"},
}).ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

Comment: This is the technique I use, and have referenced it in another question [http://stackoverflow.com/a/26744471/2108310](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26744471/2108310)  

The only difference is that I use an array of KeyValue pairs... other than needing the reference to System.Net (which is available PCL as you stated) this is IMHO the simplest way to do it without including some third party package, or trying to hobble together some homebrew spaghetti mess.

Answer (score 14):

How about creating extension methods that allow you to add the parameters in a fluent style like this?

```
string a = "http://www.somedomain.com/somepage.html"
    .AddQueryParam("A", "TheValueOfA")
    .AddQueryParam("B", "TheValueOfB")
    .AddQueryParam("Z", "TheValueOfZ");

string b = new StringBuilder("http://www.somedomain.com/anotherpage.html")
    .AddQueryParam("A", "TheValueOfA")
    .AddQueryParam("B", "TheValueOfB")
    .AddQueryParam("Z", "TheValueOfZ")
    .ToString();
```

Here's the overload that uses a `string`:

```
public static string AddQueryParam(
    this string source, string key, string value)
{
    string delim;
    if ((source == null) || !source.Contains("?"))
    {
        delim = "?";
    }
    else if (source.EndsWith("?") || source.EndsWith("&"))
    {
        delim = string.Empty;
    }
    else
    {
        delim = "&";
    }

    return source + delim + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(key)
        + "=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(value);
}
```

And here's the overload that uses a `StringBuilder`:

```
public static StringBuilder AddQueryParam(
    this StringBuilder source, string key, string value)
{
    bool hasQuery = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; i++)
    {
        if (source[i] == '?')
        {
            hasQuery = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    string delim;
    if (!hasQuery)
    {
        delim = "?";
    }
    else if ((source[source.Length - 1] == '?')
        || (source[source.Length - 1] == '&'))
    {
        delim = string.Empty;
    }
    else
    {
        delim = "&";
    }

    return source.Append(delim).Append(HttpUtility.UrlEncode(key))
        .Append("=").Append(HttpUtility.UrlEncode(value));
}
```

Comment: :+1: for the simple String-based extension method. Some of the other answers may cover more edge cases, but this is sufficient for my situation, and it does not require me to construct a `NameValueCollection`, `HttpValueCollection`, or a `Uri` first. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

```
    public static string ToQueryString(this Dictionary<string, string> source)
    {
        return String.Join("&", source.Select(kvp => String.Format("{0}={1}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(kvp.Key), HttpUtility.UrlEncode(kvp.Value))).ToArray());
    }

    public static string ToQueryString(this NameValueCollection source)
    {
        return String.Join("&", source.Cast<string>().Select(key => String.Format("{0}={1}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(key), HttpUtility.UrlEncode(source[key]))).ToArray());
    }
```

Comment: Nice! But you don't need the `.ToArray()`s.

Answer (score 10):

In dotnet core QueryHelpers.AddQueryString() will accept an IDictionary<string,string> of key-value pairs. To save a few memory allocs and CPU cycles you can use SortedList<,> instead of Dictionary<,>, with an appropriate capacity and items added in sort order...

```
var queryParams = new SortedList<string,string>(2);
queryParams.Add("abc", "val1");
queryParams.Add("def", "val2");

string requestUri = QueryHelpers.AddQueryString("https://localhost/api", queryParams);
```

Comment: While this seems to be a very elegant solution with .NET Core there is an issue because it does not support arrays. I try to send a list of IDs.  https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/7945

Answer (score 9):

Add this class to your project

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

public class QueryStringBuilder
{
    private readonly List<KeyValuePair<string, object>> _list;

    public QueryStringBuilder()
    {
        _list = new List<KeyValuePair<string, object>>();
    }

    public void Add(string name, object value)
    {
        _list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>(name, value));
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Join("&", _list.Select(kvp => String.Concat(Uri.EscapeDataString(kvp.Key), "=", Uri.EscapeDataString(kvp.Value.ToString()))));
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
var actual = new QueryStringBuilder {
    {"foo", 123},
    {"bar", "val31"},
    {"bar", "val32"}
};

actual.Add("a+b", "c+d");

actual.ToString(); // "foo=123&bar=val31&bar=val32&a%2bb=c%2bd"
```

Comment: Now, this should be the accepted answer; works perfectly for arrays like "foo[]=1,foo[]=2" as well as keeping the order of parameters which is very important by the way.

Answer (score 8):

Untested, but I think something along these lines would work quite nicely

```
public class QueryString
{
    private Dictionary<string,string> _Params = new Dictionary<string,string>();

    public overide ToString()
    {
        List<string> returnParams = new List<string>();

        foreach (KeyValuePair param in _Params)
        {
            returnParams.Add(String.Format("{0}={1}", param.Key, param.Value));
        }

        // return String.Format("?{0}", String.Join("&", returnParams.ToArray())); 

        // credit annakata
        return "?" + String.Join("&", returnParams.ToArray());
    }

    public void Add(string key, string value)
    {
        _Params.Add(key, HttpUtility.UrlEncode(value));
    }
}

QueryString query = new QueryString();

query.Add("param1", "value1");
query.Add("param2", "value2");

return query.ToString();
```

Comment: nicely encapsulated but that format on "?{0}" is kind of unnecessarily expensive :)

Comment: changed the class name to QueryString.. Query is a little ambiguous

Answer (score 7):

My offering:

```
public static Uri AddQuery(this Uri uri, string name, string value)
{
    // this actually returns HttpValueCollection : NameValueCollection
    // which uses unicode compliant encoding on ToString()
    var query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uri.Query);

    query.Add(name, value);

    var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(uri)
    {
        Query = query.ToString()
    };

    return uriBuilder.Uri;
}
```

Usage:

```
var uri = new Uri("http://stackoverflow.com").AddQuery("such", "method")
                                             .AddQuery("wow", "soFluent");

// http://stackoverflow.com?such=method&wow=soFluent
```

Comment: I prefer your approach Simple and Elegant, However, HttpUtility requires System.Web

Answer (score 6):

Combined the top answers to create an **anonymous object version**:

```
var queryString = HttpUtility2.BuildQueryString(new
{
    key2 = "value2",
    key1 = "value1",
});
```

That generates this:

> > key2=value2&key1=value1

Here's the code:

```
public static class HttpUtility2
{
    public static string BuildQueryString<T>(T obj)
    {
        var queryString = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);

        foreach (var property in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T)).Cast<PropertyDescriptor>())
        {
            var value = (property.GetValue(obj) ?? "").ToString();
            queryString.Add(property.Name, value);
        }

        return queryString.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Using dnamic object and Reflection instead of other options like NameValueCollection does not seem to be good idea. Consider if query param names are unknown (variable) as in some web api's

Answer (score 6):

There's lots of good answers here but for those using modern C# this may be a nice utility class to keep around.

```
public class QueryParamBuilder
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, string> _fields = new();
    public QueryParamBuilder Add(string key, string value)
    {
        _fields.Add(key, value);
        return this;
    }
    public string Build()
    {
        return $"?{String.Join("&", _fields.Select(pair => $"{HttpUtility.UrlEncode(pair.Key)}={HttpUtility.UrlEncode(pair.Value)}"))}";
    }
    public static QueryParamBuilder New => new();
}
```

I use an internal `Dictionary` here because dictionaries are enumerable key value pairs internally which makes iterating over them much easier than a `NameValueCollection`.

Then the query string itself is a simple interpolated string with a join.

Additionally I provide a static interface into the constructor to make the construction of a new builder very easy and only allow one exposed method `Add` to add new query parameter values.  Finally you terminate the chain with `Build()` to actually get the final string.

Here's an example of its usage

```
var queryString = QueryParamBuilder.New
     .Add("id", "0123")
     .Add("value2", 1234.ToString())
     .Add("valueWithSpace","value with spa12!@#@!ce")
     .Build();
```

The result is as expected

```
?id=0123&value2=1234&valueWithSpace=value+with+spa12!%40%23%40!ce
```

Hopefully some of you will find this nice and elegant.

Comment: Some servers accept duplicating keys and convert them to an array of values for the duplicating key. In the suggested implementation you're using Dictionary which wouldn't allow duplicate keys.

Answer (score 5):

A quick extension method based version:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var parameters = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
                             {
                                 new KeyValuePair<string, string>("A", "AValue"),
                                 new KeyValuePair<string, string>("B", "BValue")
                             };

        string output = "?" + string.Join("&", parameters.ConvertAll(param => param.ToQueryString()).ToArray());
    }
}

public static class KeyValueExtensions
{
    public static string ToQueryString(this KeyValuePair<string, string> obj)
    {
        return obj.Key + "=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(obj.Value);
    }
}
```

You could use a where clause to select which parameters get added to the string.

Answer (score 4):

Chain-able wrapper class for HttpValueCollection:

```
namespace System.Web.Mvc {
    public class QueryStringBuilder {
        private NameValueCollection collection;
        public QueryStringBuilder() {
            collection = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);
        }
        public QueryStringBuilder Add(string key, string value) {
            collection.Add(key, value);
            return this;
        }
        public QueryStringBuilder Remove(string key) {
            collection.Remove(key);
            return this;
        }
        public string this[string key] {
            get { return collection[key]; }
            set { collection[key] = value; }
        }
        public string ToString() {
            return collection.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
QueryStringBuilder parameters = new QueryStringBuilder()
    .Add("view", ViewBag.PageView)
    .Add("page", ViewBag.PageNumber)
    .Add("size", ViewBag.PageSize);
string queryString = parameters.ToString();
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you want to reduce dependencies to other assemblies and to keep things simple, you can do:

```
var sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

sb.Append("a=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("TheValueOfA") + "&");
sb.Append("b=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("TheValueOfB") + "&");
sb.Append("c=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("TheValueOfC") + "&");
sb.Append("d=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("TheValueOfD") + "&");

sb.Remove(sb.Length-1, 1); // Remove the final '&'

string result = sb.ToString();
```

This works well with loops too.  The final ampersand removal needs to go outside of the loop.

Note that the concatenation operator is used to improve readability.  The cost of using it compared to the cost of using a StringBuilder is minimal (I think [Jeff Atwood](http://www.codinghorror.com/) posted something on this topic).

Answer (score 3):

While not elegant, I opted for a simpler version that doesn't use `NameValueCollecitons` - just a builder pattern wrapped around `StringBuilder`.

```
public class UrlBuilder
{
    #region Variables / Properties

    private readonly StringBuilder _builder;

    #endregion Variables / Properties

    #region Constructor

    public UrlBuilder(string urlBase)
    {
        _builder = new StringBuilder(urlBase);
    }

    #endregion Constructor

    #region Methods

    public UrlBuilder AppendParameter(string paramName, string value)
    {
        if (_builder.ToString().Contains("?"))
            _builder.Append("&");
        else
            _builder.Append("?");

        _builder.Append(HttpUtility.UrlEncode(paramName));
        _builder.Append("=");
        _builder.Append(HttpUtility.UrlEncode(value));

        return this;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return _builder.ToString();
    }

    #endregion Methods
}
```

Per existing answers, I made sure to use `HttpUtility.UrlEncode` calls.  It's used like so:

```
string url = new UrlBuilder("http://www.somedomain.com/")
             .AppendParameter("a", "true")
             .AppendParameter("b", "muffin")
             .AppendParameter("c", "muffin button")
             .ToString();
// Result: http://www.somedomain.com?a=true&b=muffin&c=muffin%20button
```

Answer (score 3):

I have an extension method for [Uri](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri) that:

- Accepts anonymous objects: `uri.WithQuery(new { name = "value" })`
- Accepts collections of `string/string` pairs (e.g. [Dictionary`2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508)).
- Accepts collections of `string/object` pairs (e.g. [RouteValueDictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.routevaluedictionary)).
- Accepts [NameValueCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.namevaluecollection)s.
- Sorts the query values by key so the same values produce equal URIs.
- Supports multiple values per key, preserving their original order.

---

The documented version can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/safakgur/10b8f8c4b3cf944968741b532b5e3c45#file-uriutils-withquery-cs).

**The extension:**

```
public static Uri WithQuery(this Uri uri, object values)
{
    if (uri == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(uri));

    if (values != null)
    {
        var query = string.Join(
            "&", from p in ParseQueryValues(values)
                 where !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(p.Key)
                 let k = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(p.Key.Trim())
                 let v = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(p.Value)
                 orderby k
                 select string.IsNullOrEmpty(v) ? k : $"{k}={v}");

        if (query.Length != 0 || uri.Query.Length != 0)
            uri = new UriBuilder(uri) { Query = query }.Uri;
    }

    return uri;
}
```

**The query parser:**

```
private static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> ParseQueryValues(object values)
{
    // Check if a name/value collection.
    var nvc = values as NameValueCollection;
    if (nvc != null)
        return from key in nvc.AllKeys
               from val in nvc.GetValues(key)
               select new KeyValuePair<string, string>(key, val);

    // Check if a string/string dictionary.
    var ssd = values as IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>>;
    if (ssd != null)
        return ssd;

    // Check if a string/object dictionary.
    var sod = values as IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>>;
    if (sod == null)
    {
        // Check if a non-generic dictionary.
        var ngd = values as IDictionary;
        if (ngd != null)
            sod = ngd.Cast<dynamic>().ToDictionary<dynamic, string, object>(
                p => p.Key.ToString(), p => p.Value as object);

        // Convert object properties to dictionary.
        if (sod == null)
            sod = new RouteValueDictionary(values);
    }

    // Normalize and return the values.
    return from pair in sod
           from val in pair.Value as IEnumerable<string>
            ?? new[] { pair.Value?.ToString() }
           select new KeyValuePair<string, string>(pair.Key, val);
}
```

---

Here are the tests:

```
var uri = new Uri("https://stackoverflow.com/yo?oldKey=oldValue");

// Test with a string/string dictionary.
var q = uri.WithQuery(new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    ["k1"] = string.Empty,
    ["k2"] = null,
    ["k3"] = "v3"
});

Debug.Assert(q == new Uri(
    "https://stackoverflow.com/yo?k1&k2&k3=v3"));

// Test with a string/object dictionary.
q = uri.WithQuery(new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    ["k1"] = "v1",
    ["k2"] = new[] { "v2a", "v2b" },
    ["k3"] = null
});

Debug.Assert(q == new Uri(
    "https://stackoverflow.com/yo?k1=v1&k2=v2a&k2=v2b&k3"));

// Test with a name/value collection.
var nvc = new NameValueCollection()
{
    ["k1"] = string.Empty,
    ["k2"] = "v2a"
};

nvc.Add("k2", "v2b");

q = uri.WithQuery(nvc);
Debug.Assert(q == new Uri(
    "https://stackoverflow.com/yo?k1&k2=v2a&k2=v2b"));

// Test with any dictionary.
q = uri.WithQuery(new Dictionary<int, HashSet<string>>
{
    [1] = new HashSet<string> { "v1" },
    [2] = new HashSet<string> { "v2a", "v2b" },
    [3] = null
});

Debug.Assert(q == new Uri(
    "https://stackoverflow.com/yo?1=v1&2=v2a&2=v2b&3"));

// Test with an anonymous object.
q = uri.WithQuery(new
{
    k1 = "v1",
    k2 = new[] { "v2a", "v2b" },
    k3 = new List<string> { "v3" },
    k4 = true,
    k5 = null as Queue<string>
});

Debug.Assert(q == new Uri(
    "https://stackoverflow.com/yo?k1=v1&k2=v2a&k2=v2b&k3=v3&k4=True&k5"));

// Keep existing query using a name/value collection.
nvc = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uri.Query);
nvc.Add("newKey", "newValue");

q = uri.WithQuery(nvc);
Debug.Assert(q == new Uri(
    "https://stackoverflow.com/yo?newKey=newValue&oldKey=oldValue"));

// Merge two query objects using the RouteValueDictionary.
var an1 = new { k1 = "v1" };
var an2 = new { k2 = "v2" };

q = uri.WithQuery(
    new RouteValueDictionary(an1).Concat(
        new RouteValueDictionary(an2)));

Debug.Assert(q == new Uri(
    "https://stackoverflow.com/yo?k1=v1&k2=v2"));
```

Answer (score 2):

Same as accepted solution, but transfred to "dot" LINQ syntax...

```
private string ToQueryString(NameValueCollection nvc)
{
    if (nvc == null) return String.Empty;
    var queryParams = 
          string.Join("&", nvc.AllKeys.Select(key => 
              string.Join("&", nvc.GetValues(key).Select(v => string.Format("{0}={1}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(key), HttpUtility.UrlEncode(v))))));
    return "?" + queryParams;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The query string can be added to a URL by:

1. create a name value collection object
2. add the query string items and their values to this object
3. encode this name value collection object to the url the code is provided in the below link

https://blog.codingnovice.com/blog

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    //declaring name value collection object
    NameValueCollection collection = new NameValueCollection();

    //adding new value to the name value collection object
    collection.Add("Id1", "wwe323");
    collection.Add("Id2", "454w");
    collection.Add("Id3", "tyt5656");
    collection.Add("Id4", "343wdsd");

    //generating query string
    string url = GenerateQueryString(collection);

    return View();
}

private string GenerateQueryString(NameValueCollection collection)
{
    var querystring = (
        from key in collection.AllKeys
        from value in collection.GetValues(key)
        select string.Format("{0}={1}",
            HttpUtility.UrlEncode(key),
            HttpUtility.UrlEncode(value))
    ).ToArray();
    return "?" + string.Join("&", querystring);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As the context of a query string often is `HttpRequest` as `Request.QueryString` used in MVC or surface controllers, why not use the built in [`QueryString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.querystring?view=aspnetcore-7.0) type instead of converting with `StringBuilder`, `NameValueCollection`, `HttpUtility`, and other custom code?

For instance, a little something like this:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;

var queryString = QueryString.Create("key1", "value1")
queryString = queryString.Add("key2", "value2");
```

Disclaimer: The `QueryString` type isn't great for reading and updating values like a `NameValueCollection`, but it's simple for creating query strings and has built-in encoding.

Answer (score 1):

I added the following method to my PageBase class.

```
protected void Redirect(string url)
    {
        Response.Redirect(url);
    }
protected void Redirect(string url, NameValueCollection querystrings)
    {
        StringBuilder redirectUrl = new StringBuilder(url);

        if (querystrings != null)
        {
            for (int index = 0; index < querystrings.Count; index++)
            {
                if (index == 0)
                {
                    redirectUrl.Append("?");
                }

                redirectUrl.Append(querystrings.Keys[index]);
                redirectUrl.Append("=");
                redirectUrl.Append(HttpUtility.UrlEncode(querystrings[index]));

                if (index < querystrings.Count - 1)
                {
                    redirectUrl.Append("&");
                }
            }
        }

        this.Redirect(redirectUrl.ToString());
    }
```

To call:

```
NameValueCollection querystrings = new NameValueCollection();    
querystrings.Add("language", "en");
querystrings.Add("id", "134");
this.Redirect("http://www.mypage.com", querystrings);
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote some extension methods that I have found very useful when working with QueryStrings.  Often I want to start with the current QueryString and modify before using it.  Something like,

```
var res = Request.QueryString.Duplicate()
  .ChangeField("field1", "somevalue")
  .ChangeField("field2", "only if following is true", true)
  .ChangeField("id", id, id>0)
  .WriteLocalPathWithQuery(Request.Url)); //Uses context to write the path
```

For more and the source: http://www.charlesrcook.com/archive/2008/07/23/c-extension-methods-for-asp.net-query-string-operations.aspx

It's basic, but I like the style.

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to throw in my 2 cents:

```
public static class HttpClientExt
{
    public static Uri AddQueryParams(this Uri uri, string query)
    {
        var ub = new UriBuilder(uri);
        ub.Query = string.IsNullOrEmpty(uri.Query) ? query : string.Join("&", uri.Query.Substring(1), query);
        return ub.Uri;
    }

    public static Uri AddQueryParams(this Uri uri, IEnumerable<string> query)
    {
        return uri.AddQueryParams(string.Join("&", query));
    } 

    public static Uri AddQueryParams(this Uri uri, string key, string value)
    {
        return uri.AddQueryParams(string.Join("=", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(key), HttpUtility.UrlEncode(value)));
    }

    public static Uri AddQueryParams(this Uri uri, params KeyValuePair<string,string>[] kvps)
    {
        return uri.AddQueryParams(kvps.Select(kvp => string.Join("=", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(kvp.Key), HttpUtility.UrlEncode(kvp.Value))));
    }

    public static Uri AddQueryParams(this Uri uri, IDictionary<string, string> kvps)
    {
        return uri.AddQueryParams(kvps.Select(kvp => string.Join("=", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(kvp.Key), HttpUtility.UrlEncode(kvp.Value))));
    }

    public static Uri AddQueryParams(this Uri uri, NameValueCollection nvc)
    {
        return uri.AddQueryParams(nvc.AllKeys.SelectMany(nvc.GetValues, (key, value) => string.Join("=", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(key), HttpUtility.UrlEncode(value))));
    }
}
```

[The docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uribuilder.query%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) say that `uri.Query` will start with a `?` if it's non-empty and you should trim it off if you're going to modify it.

Note that `HttpUtility.UrlEncode` is found in `System.Web`.

**Usage:**

```
var uri = new Uri("https://api.del.icio.us/v1/posts/suggest").AddQueryParam("url","http://stackoverflow.com")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// USAGE
[TestMethod]
public void TestUrlBuilder()
{
    Console.WriteLine(
        new UrlBuilder("http://www.google.com?A=B")
            .AddPath("SomePathName")
            .AddPath("AnotherPathName")
            .SetQuery("SomeQueryKey", "SomeQueryValue")
            .AlterQuery("A", x => x + "C"));
}
```

Output:

> http://www.google.com/SomePathName/AnotherPathName?A=BC&SomeQueryKey=SomeQueryValue

The code; you can all thank me somewhere, somehow :D

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

// By Demetris Leptos
namespace TheOperator.Foundation.Web
{
    public class UrlBuilder
    {
        public string Scheme { get; set; }

        public string Host { get; set; }

        public int? Port { get; set; }

        public List<string> Paths { get; set; }

        public SortedDictionary<string, string> QueryPairs { get; set; }

        public UrlBuilder(string url)
        {
            this.Paths = new List<string>();
            this.QueryPairs = new SortedDictionary<string, string>();

            string path = null;
            string query = null;
            Uri relativeUri = null;
            if (!Uri.TryCreate(url, UriKind.Relative, out relativeUri))
            {
                var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(url);
                this.Scheme = uriBuilder.Scheme;
                this.Host = uriBuilder.Host;
                this.Port = uriBuilder.Port;
                path = uriBuilder.Path;
                query = uriBuilder.Query;
            }
            else
            {
                var queryIndex = url.IndexOf('?');
                if (queryIndex >= 0)
                {
                    path = url.Substring(0, queryIndex);
                    query = url.Substring(queryIndex + 1);
                }
                else
                {
                    path = url;
                }
            }
            this.Paths.AddRange(path.Split(new char[] { '/' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
            if (query != null)
            {
                var queryKeyValuePairs = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(query);
                foreach (var queryKey in queryKeyValuePairs.AllKeys)
                {
                    this.QueryPairs[queryKey] = queryKeyValuePairs[queryKey];
                }
            }
        }

        public UrlBuilder AddPath(string value)
        {
            this.Paths.Add(value);
            return this;
        }

        public UrlBuilder SetQuery(string key, string value)
        {
            this.QueryPairs[key] = value;
            return this;
        }

        public UrlBuilder RemoveQuery(string key)
        {
            this.QueryPairs.Remove(key);
            return this;
        }

        public UrlBuilder AlterQuery(string key, Func<string, string> alterMethod, bool removeOnNull = false)
        {
            string value;
            this.QueryPairs.TryGetValue(key, out value);
            value = alterMethod(value);
            if (removeOnNull && value == null)
            {
                return this.RemoveQuery(key);
            }
            else
            {
                return this.SetQuery(key, value);
            }
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            var path = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.Host)
                ? string.Join("/", this.Host, string.Join("/", this.Paths))
                : string.Join("/", this.Paths);
            var query = string.Join("&", this.QueryPairs.Select(x => string.Concat(x.Key, "=", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(x.Value))));
            return string.Concat(
                !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.Scheme) ? string.Concat(this.Scheme, "://") : null,
                path,
                !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(query) ? string.Concat("?", query) : null);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I went with the solution proposed by DSO (answered on Aug 2 '11 at 7:29), his solution does not require using HttpUtility. However, as per an article posted in [Dotnetpearls](https://www.dotnetperls.com/namevaluecollection), using a Dictionary is faster (in performance) than using NameValueCollection. Here is DSO's solution modified to use Dictionary in place of NameValueCollection.

```
    public static Dictionary<string, string> QueryParametersDictionary()
    {
        var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        dictionary.Add("name", "John Doe");
        dictionary.Add("address.city", "Seattle");
        dictionary.Add("address.state_code", "WA");
        dictionary.Add("api_key", "5352345263456345635");

        return dictionary;
    }

    public static string ToQueryString(Dictionary<string, string> nvc)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        bool first = true;

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in nvc)
        {
                if (!first)
                {
                    sb.Append("&");
                }

                sb.AppendFormat("{0}={1}", Uri.EscapeDataString(pair.Key), Uri.EscapeDataString(pair.Value));

                first = false;
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It is really amazing that if we want to have multiple instances of a name in the query string, for example, "type=10&type=21", then we can use `NameValueCollection` too. Let me show an example:

```
string MakeQueryString(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> nameValues)
{
    NameValueCollection queryParameters = 
        HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> name in nameValues)
    {
        queryParameters.Add($"{name.Key}", name.Value);
    }

    return $"?{queryParameters}";
}
```

So it can be seen that multiple instances of a name should be but in an array of `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>>`. So the complete example of creation looks like this:

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> nameValues = new ()
{
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("param1", $"1"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("param2", $"2"),
};

int[] numbers = new[] { 3, 4, 5 };
foreach (int number in numbers) 
{
    nameValues.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("param3", $"{number}"));
}

string queryString = MakeQueryString(PrepareQueryParameters(nameValues));
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a helper for my razor project using some of the hints from other answers.

The ParseQueryString business is necessary because we are not allowed to tamper with the QueryString object of the current request.

```
@helper GetQueryStringWithValue(string key, string value) {
    var queryString = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString.ToString());
    queryString[key] = value;
    @Html.Raw(queryString.ToString())
}
```

I use it like this:

```
location.search = '?@Helpers.GetQueryStringWithValue("var-name", "var-value")';
```

If you want it to take more than one value, just change the parameters to a Dictionary and add the pairs to the query string.

Answer (score 0):

The code below  is taken off the `HttpValueCollection` implementation of `ToString`, via ILSpy, which gives you a name=value querystring.

Unfortunately HttpValueCollection is an internal class which you only ever get back if you use `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString()`. I removed all the viewstate parts to it, and it encodes by default:

```
public static class HttpExtensions
{
    public static string ToQueryString(this NameValueCollection collection)
    {
        // This is based off the NameValueCollection.ToString() implementation
        int count = collection.Count;
        if (count == 0)
            return string.Empty;

        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            string text = collection.GetKey(i);
            text = HttpUtility.UrlEncodeUnicode(text);
            string value = (text != null) ? (text + "=") : string.Empty;
            string[] values = collection.GetValues(i);
            if (stringBuilder.Length > 0)
            {
                stringBuilder.Append('&');
            }
            if (values == null || values.Length == 0)
            {
                stringBuilder.Append(value);
            }
            else
            {
                if (values.Length == 1)
                {
                    stringBuilder.Append(value);
                    string text2 = values[0];
                    text2 = HttpUtility.UrlEncodeUnicode(text2);
                    stringBuilder.Append(text2);
                }
                else
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < values.Length; j++)
                    {
                        if (j > 0)
                        {
                            stringBuilder.Append('&');
                        }
                        stringBuilder.Append(value);
                        string text2 = values[j];
                        text2 = HttpUtility.UrlEncodeUnicode(text2);
                        stringBuilder.Append(text2);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return stringBuilder.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the identical to the accepted answer except slightly more compact:

```
private string ToQueryString(NameValueCollection nvc)
{
    return "?" + string.Join("&", nvc.AllKeys.Select(k => string.Format("{0}={1}", 
        HttpUtility.UrlEncode(k), 
        HttpUtility.UrlEncode(nvc[k]))));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for those that need the VB.NET version of the top-answer:

```
Public Function ToQueryString(nvc As System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection) As String
    Dim array As String() = nvc.AllKeys.SelectMany(Function(key As String) nvc.GetValues(key), Function(key As String, value As String) String.Format("{0}={1}", System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(key), System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(value))).ToArray()
    Return "?" + String.Join("&", array)
End Function
```

And the version without LINQ:

```
Public Function ToQueryString(nvc As System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection) As String
    Dim lsParams As New List(Of String)()

    For Each strKey As String In nvc.AllKeys
        Dim astrValue As String() = nvc.GetValues(strKey)

        For Each strValue As String In astrValue
            lsParams.Add(String.Format("{0}={1}", System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(strKey), System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(strValue)))
        Next ' Next strValue
    Next ' strKey
    Dim astrParams As String() = lsParams.ToArray()
    lsParams.Clear()
    lsParams = Nothing

    Return "?" + String.Join("&", astrParams)
End Function ' ToQueryString
```

And the C# version without LINQ:

```
    public static string ToQueryString(System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection nvc)
    {
        List<string> lsParams = new List<string>();

        foreach (string strKey in nvc.AllKeys)
        {
            string[] astrValue = nvc.GetValues(strKey);

            foreach (string strValue in astrValue)
            {
                lsParams.Add(string.Format("{0}={1}", System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(strKey), System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(strValue)));
            } // Next strValue

        } // Next strKey

        string[] astrParams =lsParams.ToArray();
        lsParams.Clear();
        lsParams = null;

        return "?" + string.Join("&", astrParams);
    } // End Function ToQueryString
```

Answer (score 0):

Works for multiple values per key in NameValueCollection.

ex: `{ {"k1", "v1"}, {"k1", "v1"} }` => `?k1=v1&k1=v1`

```
/// <summary>
/// Get query string for name value collection.
/// </summary>
public static string ToQueryString(this NameValueCollection collection,
    bool prefixQuestionMark = true)
{
    collection.NullArgumentCheck();
    if (collection.Keys.Count == 0)
    {
        return "";
    }
    var buffer = new StringBuilder();
    if (prefixQuestionMark)
    {
        buffer.Append("?");
    }
    var append = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < collection.Keys.Count; i++)
    {
        var key = collection.Keys[i];
        var values = collection.GetValues(key);
        key.NullCheck();
        values.NullCheck();
        foreach (var value in values)
        {
            if (append)
            {
                buffer.Append("&");
            }
            append = true;
            buffer.AppendFormat("{0}={1}", key.UrlEncode(), value.UrlEncode());
        }
    }
    return buffer.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another (**maybe redundant :-]**) way for do that.

The conceptuals are the same of the [**Vedran**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/769137/vedran) answer in this page (take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10836145/1401886)).

But this class is more efficient, because it iterate through all Keys only one time: when `ToString` is invoked.

The formatting code is also semplified and improved.

Hope that could be helpful.

```
public sealed class QueryStringBuilder
{
    public QueryStringBuilder()
    {
        this.inner = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);
    }

    public QueryStringBuilder(string queryString)
    {
        this.inner = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(queryString);
    }

    public QueryStringBuilder(string queryString, Encoding encoding)
    {
        this.inner = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(queryString, encoding);
    }

    private readonly NameValueCollection inner;

    public QueryStringBuilder AddKey(string key, string value)
    {
        this.inner.Add(key, value);
        return this;
    }

    public QueryStringBuilder RemoveKey(string key)
    {
        this.inner.Remove(key);
        return this;
    }

    public QueryStringBuilder Clear()
    {
        this.inner.Clear();
        return this;
    }

    public override String ToString()
    {
        if (this.inner.Count == 0)
            return string.Empty;

        var builder = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < this.inner.Count; i++)
        {
            if (builder.Length > 0)
                builder.Append('&');

            var key = this.inner.GetKey(i);
            var values = this.inner.GetValues(i);

            if (key == null || values == null || values.Length == 0)
                continue;

            for (int j = 0; j < values.Length; j++)
            {
                if (j > 0)
                    builder.Append('&');

                builder.Append(HttpUtility.UrlEncode(key));
                builder.Append('=');
                builder.Append(HttpUtility.UrlEncode(values[j]));
            }
        }

        return builder.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to create an extension of the class NameValueCollection that returns the complete Url:

```
public static class CustomMethods
{
    public static string ToUrl(this System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection collection)
    {
        if (collection.Count == 0) return "";

        string completeUrl = "?";
        for (int i = 0; i < collection.Count; i++)
        {
            completeUrl += new Page().Server.UrlEncode(collection.GetKey(i)) + "=" + new Page().Server.UrlEncode(collection.Get(i));
            if ((i + 1) < collection.Count) completeUrl += "&";
        }

        return completeUrl;
    }
}
```

Then, you can use your new method, for example:

```
System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection qString = new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection();
qString.Add("name", "MyName");
qString.Add("email", "myemail@test.com");
qString.ToUrl(); //Result: "?name=MyName&email=myemail%40test.com"
```

Answer (score 0):

One modern approach for .NET projects (when not in ASP.NET with QueryString).

**Extension method**

```cs
public static class QueryStringHelper
{
    [Pure]
    public static string ToQueryString(this IDictionary<string, object?>? dict)
    {
        var queryParams = dict?
            .Where(kvp => kvp.Value != null)
            .Select(kvp => $"{HttpUtility.UrlEncode(kvp.Key)}={HttpUtility.UrlEncode(kvp.Value!.ToString())}")
            .ToArray();

        if (queryParams is not { Length: > 0 }) 
            return "";

        return $"?{string.Join('&', queryParams)}";
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```cs
var queryParams = new Dictionary<string, object?>
{
    { "p1", "v1" },
    { "p2", 2 },
    { "p3", null }, // null: parameter ignored
    { "p4", false },
}.ToQueryString();
```

Result:
?p1=v1&p2=2&p4=false

Answer (score -2):

Here is an implementation which uses very basic language features.  It's part of a class which we have to port and maintain in Objective C so we choose to have more lines of code but easier to port and understand by a programmer that isn't very familiar with C#.

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Builds a complete http url with query strings.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="pHostname"></param>
        /// <param name="pPort"></param>
        /// <param name="pPage">ex "/index.html" or index.html</param>
        /// <param name="pGetParams">a Dictionary<string,string> collection containing the key value pairs.  Pass null if there are none.</param>
        /// <returns>a string of the form: http://[pHostname]:[pPort/[pPage]?key1=val1&key2=val2...</returns>

  static public string buildURL(string pHostname, int pPort, string pPage, Dictionary<string,string> pGetParams)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(200);
            sb.Append("http://");
            sb.Append(pHostname);
            if( pPort != 80 ) {
                sb.Append(pPort);
            }
            // Allows page param to be passed in with or without leading slash.
            if( !pPage.StartsWith("/") ) {
                sb.Append("/");
            }
            sb.Append(pPage);

            if (pGetParams != null && pGetParams.Count > 0)
            {
                sb.Append("?");
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in pGetParams)
                {
                    sb.Append(kvp.Key);
                    sb.Append("=");
                    sb.Append( System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(kvp.Value) );
                    sb.Append("&");
                }
                sb.Remove(sb.Length - 1, 1); // Remove the final '&'
            }
            return sb.ToString();
        }
```

Answer (score -3):

```
public string UrlQueryStr(object data)
{
    if (data == null)
        return string.Empty;

    object val;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(data))
    {
        if ((val = prop.GetValue(data)) != null)
        {
            sb.AppendFormat("{0}{1}={2}", sb.Length == 0 ? '?' : '&',
                HttpUtility.UrlEncode(prop.Name), HttpUtility.UrlEncode(val.ToString()));
        }
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score -6):

EDIT - as pointed out in the comments, this is not the way to go.

There is such a class - the URI Class. "Provides an object representation of a uniform resource identifier (URI) and easy access to the parts of the URI." (Microsoft docs).

The following example creates an instance of the Uri class and uses it to create a WebRequest instance.

C#  example

Uri siteUri = new Uri("http://www.contoso.com/");

WebRequest wr = WebRequest.Create(siteUri);

Check it out, there are lots of methods on this class.

Comment: the Uri class has no methods to manage the query string, other then getting it and setting it (and I'm not sure about the latter)

Comment: The Uri class is good *once you have a URI built including the query.* Uri is immutable so you can't add to it once it's created. There is the UriBuilder class, but IIRC it doesn't have a method for query string; it's still left to the programmer to create it.

The Uri class is good once you have it constructed for things like proper escaping.