# HttpUtility.UrlEncode in Windows Phone 7?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

The regular .Net framework contains HttpUtility.UrlEncode in the System.Web Assembly and in Silverlight it appears it was moved to System.Windows.Browser. But in Windows Phone 7 (which I thought was the same as Silverlight) I can't seem to find a proper way to UrlEncode anything. Neither of the previously mentioned assemblies are available in the Windows Phone 7 environment.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Silverlight has the [Uri.EscapeUriString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.escapeuristring(v=VS.95).aspx) and [Uri.EscapeDataString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.escapedatastring(v=VS.95).aspx) which can be used to URL-encode portions of a URI such as query strings and path components and such.

Even in the desktop framework, you should never take a dependency on System.Web.dll just for HttpUtility, although many developers still do it. This is bad for 3 reasons.

- The assembly is very large and loading it can add significant delays to your application.
- You will be bloating the working set of your process for about 20 lines of code.
- It makes your application require the full framework since System.Web is not in the client profile.

In addition to the Uri escaping methods described above, if you need HtmlEncode, I would just rip code off [that someone else wrote](http://code.google.com/p/google-gdata/source/browse/trunk/clients/cs/src/core/HttpUtility.cs?r=961) and drop it in your application.

Comment: +1, also the correct approach in any .NET client application not just Silverlgiht.  HttpUtility is in the System.Web.dll which is designed to deliver the Server end of the Web.

Comment: Indeed I just wrote a twitter view / search app which uses this so they do work.

Comment: Regarding HtmlEncode/HtmlDecode, it's not only at System.Web of full .NET framework: .NET 4 Client Profile has System.Net.WebUtility, Silverlight has System.Windows.Browser.HttpUtility and Windows Phone has System.Net.HttpUtility

Comment: at http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2009/Feb/05/Html-and-Uri-String-Encoding-without-SystemWeb it is suggesting:  "pre-process for + sign space formatting since System.Uri doesn't handle it, plus literals are encoded as %2b normally so this should be safe" -  public static string UrlDecode(string text) {text = text.Replace("+", " "); return System.Uri.UnescapeDataString(text); }

Answer (score 25):

`HttpUtility.UrlEncode` and `HttpUtility.UrlDecode` are in Windows Phone 7, they just got moved.

Look for them in `System.Net.HttpUtility` in assembly System.Windows.dll.

Answer (score 0):

Now it is solved. You can use :

```
Windows.Data.Html.HtmlUtilities.ConvertToText("your_html_string");
```