# Windows Phone SDK - What can I use instead of System.Web?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I am fairly new to `Windows Phone` development, and I have a lot of classes that I thought would be straightforward by using some function in **`System.Web`** (namely, `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString`). But it seems that **`System.Web`** is not available on `Windows Phone`?

Is this correct? Or might I just be missing a way of adding it?

I'd really like to not have to hand write functions like `ParseQueryString`.

Any advice on how to get a reference to **`System.Web`** in my `Windows Phone` app?

Cheers!
Brett

Answer (score 2):

It seems there are no such methods available in widows phone sdk, You can use your own code like this http://code.google.com/p/google-gdata/source/browse/trunk/clients/cs/src/core/HttpUtility.cs?r=961

More info you can get at this discussion, 
[HttpUtility.UrlEncode in Windows Phone 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573290/httputility-urlencode-in-windows-phone-7)

Answer (score 1):

Now It is solved by using this :

```
Windows.Data.Html.HtmlUtilities.ConvertToText("your_html_string");
```