# How to find out the right encoding of a webservice respose?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, encoding, webclient

I'm developing a Windows pone 8 application that is calling a third party web service. That service is returning some text with the following response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: xxxxxxxxxx
Server: Apache/xxxxxxxxx
X-Powered-By: PHP/5xxxxxxxxxx
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html
```

I'm getting the information from the web service using a `WebClient` and the `UploadStringAsync` method. On the response I'm getting characters like á and others ... How can I fix this? I've tried changing the WebClient encoding (without knowing too much what I'm really doing) without success.

**EDIT:**

I'm reveiving a JSON response which contains text like this one (in several languages apart from english):

> "description":"Podcast del programa de Radio El D& iacute;a. Aqu& iacute; encontrar& aacute;s d& iacute;a a d& iacute;a"

[I have added spaces between the & and the other characters because otherwise SO shows the correct text]

Comment: Is it really returning HTML? Then it's probably an error message, not a web service response.

Comment: What is the response you are receiving and what are you expecting?

Comment: @JohnSaunders: its returning a JSON response containing strings formatted like HTML ... that is out of my control or maybe I'm doing the request wrong or it's missing some important header.

Comment: @Joe: check the edit. That's the response I'm receiving while I would like to have the string with the á é í ó ú instead of & iacute, etc ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The accented special characters are being returned from the webservice because [ISO-8859-1](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_entities.asp) is the default character set in most browsers, and you can just send the resulting strings to a browser for the correct decoding.

But, since you're not sending it to a browser, you can also decode them yourself with :

```
string json = "Podcast del programa de Radio El D&iacute;a. Aqu&iacute; encontrar&aacute;s d&iacute;a a d&iacute;a";
string decoded = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(json);
```

From [this SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573290/httputility-urlencode-in-windows-phone-7) you'll be directed [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-gdata/source/browse/trunk/clients/cs/src/core/HttpUtility.cs?r=961) for a version of HttpUtility which you can run on Windows Phone.