# C# ASP.NET : Dynamically constructing an url query string

Tags: c#, asp.net, query-string

I need to dynamically construct a url by appending new parameter to the current url.

I know how to do this in the long way by getting the current url and check if there is any QueryString, if no add "?" if yes add "&". Also check is the parameter is already exist. If yes change the value.

But is there any build in .NET function to do this? Like Request.QueryString.Add

Thanks.

Comment: sounds like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/829080/how-to-build-a-query-string-for-a-url-in-c

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no built-in method in .Net, you'll have to check manually if url contains `?` then add new querystring. or if the parameter already exists then update the value.