# search button in page and pass item as query string

Tags: asp.net, query-string

I have search button on page. user input som data and click search button.
how can search with query string (like google search).
is it correct:

```
void search_click(...)
{
   string item1 = text1.text;
   string item2 = text2.text;
   Responce.Redirect(currentPage.html?x=item1&y=item2);
}
```

or has better solution.(c#)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use **GET** method on your search form.

Probably the easiest way would be not using **ASP.NET controls** and using plain **HTML components** instead:

```
<form method="get" target="search.aspx">
    Search: <input type="text" name="q" value="Search"><br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Then, when the user clicks on **Search** button, the user will be taken to a place with a URL like:

```
http://YOUR_SERVER/YOUR_APP/search.aspx?q=hello
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the answer to the same question here: [How to build a query string for a URL in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/829080/how-to-build-a-query-string-for-a-url-in-c)

You can build a NameValueCollection and output it as the proper format. The top answer has a great example.

Comment: you dont understand my question.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has some errors. Use the following:

```
Responce.Redirect("currentPage.html?x=" + item1 + "&y=" + item2);
```