# Mvc4 Model to url querystring

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm looking for a way to convert a mvc4 model to querystring.
The built-in mechanism of mvc4 is allowing me to do something like this:

```
@Url.Action("SearchWithQueryString","Search", new {@Title = "Title", @Author= " Author", @Date = "date"})
```

The result of this command is:

```
Url/Search/SearchWithQueryString?Title=title&Author=author&date=date
```

**My goal** is to pass a poco model and get the same result.
for example, if I have this class:

```
public class Test
{
    public string Title {get;set;}
    public string Author {get;set;}
    public string Date {get;set;}
}
```

I want to be able to do something like this with using the built-in mechanism:

```
@Url.Action("SearchWithQueryString","Search", new Test())
```

and get the same result as I got previously.

Any ideas?

Comment: You check this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9817591/convert-querystring-from-to-object

Comment: This is the trivial solution. reflection.
I want to use the build-in mechanism to avoid from creating new code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the [`RouteValueDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.routevaluedictionary%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class. This allows you to convert a model to a QueryString:

```
@Url.Action("SearchWithQueryString", "Search", new RouteValueDictionary(new Test()))
```

Where `new Test()` could also be `Model` for example.