# Convert from Object to QueryString

Tags: c#, json, object

How can I covert this object string

```
products=[{"PRICE":39.95,"RECIPIENT":{"ZIPCODE":"11779"},"CODE":"F1-509"}]
```

to QueryString in C# as a parameter in an URL?

I still have a problem because products - a JSON encoded string containing an array of product structures .Products is the parameter of the URL which the RECIPIENT object is inside RootObject.

```
var order = new RootObject()

        {
            Price = 39.95,
            Code = "F1-509",
            Recipient = new RECIPIENT
            {
                Zipcode = "11779"
            }
        };
```

I need to convert Products Parameter to query which pass by URL in C# with GetAsync(URL).

Comment: If this is a small object you can split it and send multiple query strings or convert it to base64 and send as a single, but it's always preferred to post objects like this instead of get

Comment: a quick google search `convert object to query string c#` displays some solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6848296/465053) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9817591/465053)

Comment: @RBT does she need to serialize the object or just `UrlEncode` it? She had a similar post to this a little while ago that is now gone. She said this was working in Postman but not working in c#. Several questions were asked which were not responded to before that question was down voted and deleted.

Comment: If you have a string then use Format :             decimal price = 39.95M;
            string zipCode = "11779";
            string code = "F1-509";
            string query = string.Format("products=[{\"PRICE\":{0},\"RECIPIENT\":{\"ZIPCODE\":\"{1}\"},\"CODE\":\"{2}\"}]", price, zipCode, code);

Comment: Fortunately I found the solution for converting array parameter to query parameter in URL.                                                                                    var queryString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(object);
var uri = WebUtility.UrlEncode(queryString);