# Raw POST data deserialization using C#/.net (bind to complex model) like in modelbinder of MVC/webApi

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, model-binding

I would like to have any ready generic solution to convert string with POST data like :

```
"id=123&eventName=eventName&site[domain][id]=123"
```

to my complex object

```
public class ComplObject {
   public int id {get;set;}
   public string eventName {get;set;}
   public siteClass site{get;set;}
}

public class siteClass {       
   public domainClass domain {get;set;}       
}

public class domainClass {
   public int id {get;set;}       
}
```

Access to asp.net MVC reference is allowed.
Looks,like i need standalone formdata binder, but i cannot find any work library/code to handle it.

Comment: It looks like you will have to manually parse out the site[domain][id] parameter.  You may have to create your ComplObject class, and then assign each of the properties a value (coming from request parameters)

Comment: Have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9817591/convert-querystring-from-to-object Not sure if there's a ready-made solution, but you can convert to Json first, then deserialize https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12428947/how-do-i-convert-a-querystring-to-a-json-string

Comment: @AnthonyMcGrath i need a generic solution, manually parse it is a bad solution in my case

Comment: @IvanZaruba i need Inverted soultion, not model to url data, so your link, unfortunately, useless

Comment: What about an extension method of `HttpRequest` who parse POST parameter and return `ComplObject` ? Is what you need ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement your custom http parameter binding by overriding the [HttpParameterBinding class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.web.http.controllers.httpparameterbinding(v=vs.118).aspx). Then create a custom attribute to use it on your web API.

Example with a parameter read from json content :

**CustomAttribute**:

```
/// <summary>
/// Define an attribute to define a parameter to be read from json content
/// </summary>
[AttributeUsageAttribute(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Parameter, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class FromJsonAttribute : ParameterBindingAttribute
{
    public override HttpParameterBinding GetBinding(HttpParameterDescriptor parameter)
    {
        return new JsonParameterBinding(parameter);
    }
}
```

**ParameterBinding :**

```
/// <summary>
/// Defines a binding for a parameter to be read from the json content
/// </summary>
public class JsonParameterBinding : HttpParameterBinding
{
...Here your deserialization logic
}
```

**WepAPi**

```
[Route("Save")]
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage Save([FromJson] string name,[FromJson] int age,[FromJson] DateTime birthday)
{
...
}
```