# Model Binding HTTP Requests in ASP.Net Core WebAPI

Tags: c#, .net, api

I'm having an issue with an endpoint, it takes an object which isn't binding and consequently returning a 400 bad request.

I've gotten around this issue by passing in the individual properties of the object rather than the object itself, but would prefer the passing of an object.

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.QueryString.Add("firstName", "value1");
webClient.QueryString.Add("lastName", "value2");
string result = webClient.DownloadString(url);

[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> DoSomething(string firstName, string lastName)
{ 
   // this endpoint works perfectly
   return Ok();
}

[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> DoSomething([FromBody]SubmitModel model)
{ 
   // this endpoint returns a 400 bad request
   return Ok();
}

public class SubmitModel
{
   public string FirstName {get; set;}
   public string LastName {get; set;
}
```

Comment: I am guessing - when you do `get`, it just makes no sense to pass a model. So, there is probably no support for it. You need to read protocol/specs. It is probably what it is

Comment: @T.S. hmm, I personally find it cleaner to have a single object over multiple params

Comment: It doesn't matter what you personally think. Only matter is REST spec. With GET you don't get to enjoy this. You have to POST something to read from request body

Comment: ASP.NET Web API has a parameter binding attribute [FromUri] to read a complex type from the url :)

Comment: That is correct. But not from body

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if there is a good way to do what you're wanting. To get a little bit closer you can add this attribute to pull directly from the url

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Get([FromUri]SubmitModel model)
{ 
   // this endpoint returns a 400 bad request
   return Ok();
}
```

Another thing you can do if need be is create an extension method that reflects over the model and adds all the properties/values to the query string. Some good examples here [How do I serialize an object into query-string format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6848296/how-do-i-serialize-an-object-into-query-string-format)

Answer (score 1):

By design, `GET` request does **not** contain data in the request body.
So when your *Submit* method recieves a request, it can't bind the model from the body as the data does not exist and therefore returns an bad request response.

As your method is named *Submit*, it sounds like you should use a `POST` request instead. `POST` request, by design, sends data in the request body and is suited for submitting data to the server.

Try it like this

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Submit([FromBody]SubmitModel model)
{ 
   // this endpoint returns a 400 bad request
   return Ok();
}
```

Comment: the example posted is a simplified version of the one posted - I've renamed the endpoint to DoSomething() as it was misleading.

Comment: I'm dealing with a GET request - according to the docs [FromQuery] may be an option.

Comment: @PaulS Ok :). Then you should use FromUri attribute. It will compose the query strings into the model object