# building a custom url

Tags: asp.net

i am building a asp.net web page where i will provide two text boxes where user can enter the `id` and `link` and once the user click the button i will generate the below ur

i have a ur like this

```
http://www.hostname.com/controller.aspx?id=123&link=abc123
```

the `id` and `link` value will provide by the user and i am looking for a way to build the url in a more optimized way.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

here is how i able to build

```
const string URL = "http://www.hostname.com/controller.aspx?id={0}&link={1}";
string.Format(URL, "123","aaa123");
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say use a combination of the System.UriBuilder class and this:

[How to build a query string for a URL in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/829080/how-to-build-a-query-string-for-a-url-in-c)