# search engine for asp.net website

Tags: c#, asp.net, search

is it a possible to make a search engine to works better than google and yahoo ?

i should do a mini project for my internet engineering course.
my website need a search engine (( `asp.net ( c# )` )) Website.

when a user search word in my website, my `search engine` should send a request to `Google,yahoo,...` and receive their first page links and show that links as a result in my Website.
in fact i need to send http request to another site and parse the results.
i don't know how should i start and how to do it.
is there any guide for this project ?

Comment: "is it a possible to make a search engine to works better than google and yahoo ?" - Yes, if you are a supremely intelligent extra-terrestrial being.

Comment: @AntP yeah i know but my actual question is that other question ;)

Comment: @oli so you aren't building a search engine, you want to know how to issue a http request to another site and parse the results?

Comment: pff google sucks, everyone can make a better one. /end joke
No its not possible, but, google has some good devtools for that

Comment: @NicholasKing yes exactly :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7908972/how-to-write-a-http-request

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Better? No.

The same, yes:

Google custom search API: https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview

Answer (score 3):

I guess you are looking for something like Google's [Custom Search Engine](http://www.google.com/cse/).

Quote from the link:

> **Make searching your site easy**
>
> Sign in to Custom Search Engine With Google Custom Search, add a
>   search box to your homepage to help people find what they need on your
>   website.

Comment: I think he's looking for an API

Comment: @Nathan i want to send a request to google and then parse the result to extract links from that page

Comment: @Oli thought so - see my answer below.

Comment: @Oli: Then Nathan's answer probably is the better solution for you.