# C# code for curl operation

Tags: c#, curl, twilio

curl for **Twilio** with out helper library

```
curl -X POST 'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/[sid]/Messages.xml' \
--data-urlencode 'To=+919400xxxxxx'  \
--data-urlencode 'From=+1484925xxxx'  \
--data-urlencode 'Body=[body]' \
-u [sid]:[AuthToken]
```

I wanted to Do it using C# code. ( I don't have much knowledge in C# )

I just checked these

1. [Making a cURL call in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7929013/making-a-curl-call-in-c-sharp)
2. [cURL with user authentication in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5152723/curl-with-user-authentication-in-c-sharp?lq=1)

But gives invalid request.

Comment: Do you seriously think that "I don't have much knowledge in C#" is a good justification for being lazy?

Comment: What is your question? Do you want to call curl from C# or do you want to make that web request directly in C#?

Comment: @zerkms I am a PHP developer. During college days I just did some C# ( about 5 years ago ). Now I accidentally met a situation to use Twilio on a ASP project. I tried something but it not work much...

Comment: @delixfe I want to make that web request directly.

Comment: @Arjun Raj: if it's a paid project - then just don't apply on something you cannot handle. If it's an educational project - learn how to program C#. Either way, asking us to code for you for free makes little to no sense.

Comment: That usage of `curl` makes an HTTP POST request with a set of arguments. You can also do this using C#, however it will have nothing to do with `curl`, per se. Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7908972/how-to-write-a-http-request).

Comment: You should write more about what you already have tried. Show your code and the errors you have gotten. Then it will be easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 3):

You can start by using Nuget to download the Twilio helpers, search for Twilio.
Once you have that package installed, you can use it like this.

```
var client = new TwilioRestClient("accountsid", "authtoken");
var result = client.SendSmsMessage("from", "to", "body");
```