# How to send POST request in Xamarin?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I've built my backend in rails.
My email address is "sample@zmail.com" and it's already registered. The password is "28902890" here

After giving the following command in terminal

```
curl -v -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/json' -X POST https://auth-agdit.herokuapp.com/api/v1/sessions -d "{\"user\":{\"email\":\"sample@zmail\",\"password\":\"28902890\"}}"
```

I get this response from my backend,

```
{"success":true,"info":"Logged in :) ","data":{"authentication_token":"iexGFwJ6HwERQZ3wJ4NG"}}
```

Now I need to get this data from my Android app.
I can get json by using WebClient().downloadString() method for simple json where authentication is not needed and the request method is GET.

Now I need to get the output Json for POST method.
How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I did it:

```
  WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        string baseSiteString = wc.DownloadString("https://auth-agdit.herokuapp.com");
        string csrfToken = Regex.Match(baseSiteString, "<meta name=\"csrf-token\" content=\"(.*?)\" />").Groups[1].Value;
        string cookie = wc.ResponseHeaders[HttpResponseHeader.SetCookie];
        Console.WriteLine("CSRF Token: {0}", csrfToken);
        Console.WriteLine("Cookie: {0}", cookie);

        wc.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, cookie);
        wc.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, "application/json; charset=utf-8");
        wc.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Accept, "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01");
        wc.Headers.Add("X-CSRF-Token", csrfToken);
        wc.Headers.Add("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");


        string dataString = @"{""user"":{""email"":""email_here"",""password"":""password_here""}}";
     //   string dataString = @"{""user"":{""email"":"""+uEmail+@""",""password"":"""+uPassword+@"""}}";
        byte[] dataBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(dataString);
        byte[] responseBytes = wc.UploadData(new Uri("https://auth-agdit.herokuapp.com/api/v1/sessions.json"), "POST", dataBytes);
        string responseString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responseBytes);
        Console.WriteLine(responseString);
```

Answer (score 3):

There are several methods of doing this. You could use the Xamarin component called [RestSharp](https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/restsharp). This will provide you with easy methods of interfacing with your backend.

```
var request = new RestRequest("resource/{id}", Method.POST);
request.AddParameter("name", "value"); // adds to POST or URL querystring based on Method
request.AddUrlSegment("id", 123); // replaces matching token in request.Resource

// add parameters for all properties on an object
request.AddObject(object);

// execute the request
RestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

If you do want to simply use the `WebClient` class provided by the BCL you can use the `WebClient.UploadString(string, string)` method like so:

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
  string json = "{\"user\":{\"email\":\"sample@zmail\",\"password\":\"28902890\"}}";
  client.UploadString("https://example.com/api/v1/sessions, json);
}
```

If you need more control over the request (such as setting accept headers, etc.) then you can use `HttpRequest`, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7909147/1411687) for an example of that.

Comment: This works but only after I added 'client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";' before UploadString()

Answer (score -1):

Try with this code:

```
Uri address = new Uri("http://example.com/insert.php");
NameValueCollection nameValueCollection = new NameValueCollection();
nameValueCollection["Name"] = "string-input";

var webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.UploadValuesAsync(address, "POST", nameValueCollection);
```