# Xamarin form application to interact with the server

Tags: xaml, c#-4.0, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

I am trying to develop a xamarin form application which is a app version of our website and I want to get data from user and save it to the server, and again retrieve the data from server and display in the app, Can anyone suggest some good code samples?

Thanks

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/web_services/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some useful links where it shows you how to do a POST/GET method of your web API and consume it on your Xamarin Application:

https://theconfuzedsourcecode.wordpress.com/2015/05/19/how-to-make-post-get-calls-to-an-asp-net-restful-web-service-in-xamarin-forms/

[Send HTTP Post request in Xamarin Forms C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36458551/send-http-post-request-in-xamarin-forms-c-sharp)

[How to send POST request in Xamarin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30148843/how-to-send-post-request-in-xamarin)

http://15mgm15.ghost.io/2017/02/08/connect-to-a-remote-database-using-xamarin-forms/

Comment: Thanks Mario, I am looking into these links :)