# WebClient, doesn't send parameters

Tags: c#, fogbugz-api

I try to get the token from my fogbugz website, folowing :

```
http://fogbugz.stackexchange.com/fogbugz-xml-api
```

I have :

```
using (var wb = new WebClient())
{   
                var data = new NameValueCollection();
                data["cmd"] = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(cmdLogon);
                data["email"] = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(email);
                data["password"] = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(password);
                content = encoding.GetString(wb.UploadValues(url, "POST", data));
 }
```

Below the Server Response :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><response><error code="1">Nom d'utilisateur ou mot de passe incorrect</error></response>
```

I can see the request in IIS logs but parameters are absent.

What I'm doing wrong?

edit : I'm sure parameters are correct cause I tested In the browser and it work well.

Comment: the error is Bad Username or password for non Fench reader.

Comment: When you say you tested it in the browser .. was this tested on your local machine vs a machine on your network / domain. perhaps the from what I can see you are only using the password.. unless cmdLogon is the user name.. but that looks to be more like a method() to call

Comment: @DJ KRAZE I don't understand what you said "you are only using the password.."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran this with Fiddler, and your code sends a request with the following content in the request body:

```
cmd=logon&email=test-email&password=test-password
```

Instead, I believe you should be sending this information in the query string as per the [documentation](http://fogbugz.stackexchange.com/fogbugz-xml-api) (see the "Logging On" section):

```
http://www.example.com/api.asp?cmd=logon&email=xxx@example.com&password=BigMac
```

If you want to use a `NameValueCollection` to build your querystring, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/829138/409259) provides a way to do that.

Comment: But I want to send my parameters by the method POST

Comment: And for information there is a section "General rules for API requests" in the documentation, who explicit that sending with POST method is allowed.