# How to add querystring for specific URL which match a controller in Mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I build an url for specific controller with:

```
 var f = new System.UriBuilder( Request.Url.AbsoluteUri ) {
           Path = Url.Action( "Get", "People")
        };
```

it returns

```
http://localhost/myApp/People/Get
```

Good.

What is the best way to add a querystring to that url ?

Means

```
http://localhost/myApp/People/Get?id=7
```

I'm going to do with :

```
string path = string.Concat(f.ToString(), "?id=3");
```

But I want to know if is other way (more better than provided by me above) to append querystring to that Url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Url.Action( "Get", "People", new { id = 7 })
```

Comment: It's because you have route for `id` param. It's actually should be `http://localhost/myApp/People/Get/7` which is redable. If you want to add exactly `?id=3` - probably concatenation is best way, or change default route to not use `id` param (which is not recomended)

Comment: I understand, that why I asked for better way to do without concatenation, I'm avoiding hardcoding.

Comment: Again, if you don't have route for `personValue` param it will generate `/People/Get?personValue=7` (just tried it)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try one of the extension methods shown here: [How to build a query string for a URL in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/829080/how-to-build-a-query-string-for-a-url-in-c)

It will lead to more code sure but more flexibility i guess.