# how to pass arguments in Json Get request

Tags: c#, json

I have a json URl like "https://landfill.bugzilla.org/bugzilla-tip/jsonrpc.cgi?method=Product.get&params=[{"ids":"4"}]"

I want to pass this as URL in c# program. below is the code snippet. How can i pass the arguments like ids as above?

```
try
{
    string url="https://landfill.bugzilla.org/bugzilla-tip/jsonrpc.cgi?method=Product.get";
    string ret = string.Empty;
    StreamWriter requestWriter;
    var webRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
    if (webRequest != null)
    {
        webRequest.Method = "GET";
        webRequest.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
        webRequest.Timeout = 20000;

        webRequest.ContentType = "application/json";        
    }
    HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
    Stream resStream = resp.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(resStream);
    ret = reader.ReadToEnd();
    return ret;
}
catch (WebException exception)
{
    string responseText;
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(exception.Response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        responseText = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
    return responseText;
}
}
```

Need to pass "ids" as argument, please help.

Comment: Not sure what is your problem - you have sample of the url in the question and using some other Url to send request... Just use the one you need... Or you asking something else (like "how to correctly construct my parameter if I have `int id = 4`:")?

Comment: Yes i want to construt the parameter, Problem is i am not able to pass the whole URL what i have given above, so i need to pass the params separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know how Url looks like and sure that argument are Url-safe (like `int`) you can simply use String.Format to construct it:

```
 int id = 4;
 var url = String.Format("https://landfill.bugzilla.org/bugzilla-tip/"
       + "jsonrpc.cgi?method=Product.get&params=[{{\"ids\":\"{0}\"}}]", id);
```

Note that this is not good way of contructing Url - it only would be ok for one-time-use code and when you know that inserted parameters are Url-safe. Proper approach would be to use Uri class or approaches from [How to build a query string for a URL in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/829080/how-to-build-a-query-string-for-a-url-in-c)

If you need ot construct more complex parameter (like array of IDs) - use jbehren suggestion for JSON serializtion.

Answer (score 2):

The hard way is to create a string manually. The better way is to use a library like JSON.Net (Newtonsoft.Json) ... Create your object, use the JSON Serializer in that lib, and you're off to the races.

A get request is simply a URL, which is a string.