# double quotation inside url c#

Tags: c#, api

Is there any way to allow the program to take my string as a whole?
I have listed an example below
For the second example, it doesn't take my entire input as a whole string. hotmail.com is blue (hyperlink) while the id = 50 is recognised as the string.
Im guessing its the double quotation marks. What can i do to solve this?

Eg:

```
1. string str = "hi";
2. string str = "http://hotmail.com/"id"=50";
```

The actual code im trying to declare:

```
string url = @"http://www.onemap.sg/advminimap/MiniMap.htm?mWidth=700&mHeight=600&searchval=&zoomLevl=7&iwt=[{""id"":2,""x"":""{0}"",""y"":""{1}"",""screenX"":undefined,""screenY"":undefined,""infoWindowText"":""{2}"",""postalCode"":""{3}"",""searchVal"":"""",""calloutWidth"":100,""calloutHeight"":100,""calloutTitle"":""{4}"",""zoomLevel"":7}, {""id"":3,""x"":""{5}"",""y"":""{6}"",""screenX"":undefined,""screenY"":undefined,""infoWindowText"":""{7}"",""postalCode"":""{8}"",""searchVal"":"""",""calloutWidth"":100,""calloutHeight"":100,""calloutTitle"":""{9}"",""zoomLevel"":7}]&check=true&calloutTitle=&calloutWidth=100&calloutHeight=100&isEdit=1&isSearch=0";
```

Comment: Use the @ in string 2.  Then escape double quotes with double double quotes, e.g., `string str = @"http://hotmail.com/""id""=50";`

Comment: Try to replace the `"` with `%22`.

Comment: Although I must say json in a GET url seems wrong

Comment: Can you all provide a snippet or example?

Comment: Replace " by %22 or Use HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w.aspx ..thanks mit

Comment: What you really should be doing build an Uri is using `UriBuilder`, `NameValuCollection` (for [Query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/829080/how-to-build-a-query-string-for-a-url-in-c) part) and one of JSON serializers (i.e. JSON.Net).

Comment: Kinda new to this, do you mind showing an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always use url encode for parts of a URL which might need to contain anything unusual....
If you want to get into the standards, refer to [RFC1738](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt)

> "...Only alphanumerics [0-9a-zA-Z], the special characters $-_.+!*'(),
>   and reserved characters used for their reserved purposes may be used
>   unencoded within a URL."

to include double quotation inside url you need to encode it to %22

Comment: Can i have a snippet?

Comment: just replace every double quotation to %22 when generating the url and replace back when reading on the destination ...

Answer (score -1):

use **\** before quotation marks inside:

> string str = "this is **\**"some quotation **\**" you need to put
>   inside of the string";