# mask query dynamic query string value

Tags: c#, asp.net, query-string, namevaluecollection

I am building a wrapper to process payments.  We want to log requests, but don't want to store sensitive credit card data. A query string will be passed similar to what is below

`amount=100.00&expMonth=01&expYear=14&cardnumber=4111111111111111`

I want to mask the first 12 digits of the credit card number with X values.  However, the cardnumber key will not always be in the same spot.

My first leaning is to create a `NameValueCollection` and check for the key and do a `string.format("XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-{0}", substring of the value`

```
var qs = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(request);
foreach (string key in qs)
{
    if (key == "creditcard")
    {

    }
}
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

I need to save the string in the same format with just the credit card number masked.

Comment: Side note: consider not putting sensitive information in Url that may be copy-pasted by a user... Generally such requests are done via post and putting information in fields (along with some sort of replay/CSRF protection)

Comment: It actually isn't coming in through a query string. It will be coming in through the body of the request. It's just passed in querystring format

Comment: Why don't you use regular ASP.Net (WebForms/MVC) mechanism than? Anyway - check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/829080/how-to-build-a-query-string-for-a-url-in-c which shows how to build it back.

Comment: What database/ORM are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works great, there may be a more elegant solution though.

```
var maskedRequest = "";
var qs = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(request);
foreach (string item in qs.AllKeys)
{
   if (item != "cardnumber")
   {
       maskedRequest = maskedRequest + item + "=" + qs.Get(item) + "&";
   }
   else
   {
       maskedRequest = maskedRequest + item + "=" + string.Format("XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-{0}", qs.Get(item).Substring(12, 4)) + "&";
    }
}

maskedRequest = maskedRequest.Remove(maskedRequest.Length - 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a sensible approach, but maybe using `Get` method on the `NameValueCollection` would be easier. Like so:

```
String maskedCardNumber = null;
var qs = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(request);
var cardNumber = qs.Get("cardnumber");
if (cardNumber != null)
{
    var substring = cardNumber.Substring(cardNumber.Length - Math.Min(4, cardNumber.Length));
    maskedCardNumber = String.Format("XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-{0}", substring);
}
```

Comment: Good solution, but now I need to put it all back together again. The string needs to be saved in it's original format with the masked credit card