# Querystring return null when using &amp; instead of & from URL

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I am using following function to get value of query string from a a URL

`contact.aspx?PID=15&Lang=en-US`   --- **Works**

`contact.aspx?PID=15&amp;Lang=en-US` --- **Fails**

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Helper.GetQueryStringValue("Lang")))
{
  //Do somthing
}


public static String GetQueryStringValue(String qValue)
{
  String value = String.Empty;
    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString[qValue] != null)
    {
      value = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString[qValue].ToString();
    }
 return value;
}
```

when i use `&amp;` in url it return null value for querystring `Lang` and when i use`&` it works.

I am not able to understand why this happens

Answer (score 2):

It has nothing do to with encoding or decoding.

The ampersand is the delimiter for the query string arguments, so what you actually have in your URL is two names: `PID` and `amp;Lang`  If you change your code to look for the latter, you'll get `en-us` as your output.

```
Response.Write(GetQueryStringValue("amp;Lang"));
```

Decoding the URL wont work because it hasn't been properly encoded to begin with. The properly encoded URL would be:

```
contact.aspx?PID%3d15%26amp%3bLang%3den-US
```

If you had that you could decode it, but it still wouldn't get you what you're looking for because you still don't have an name called `Lang`; even after decoding it's still `amp;Lang`

Also, this is totally unrelated, but the `ToString()` is redundant in the `GetQueryStringValue` function.  That line can simply be:

```
value = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString[qValue];
```

Comment: What if i have some url with `&amp;` and some with `&`... my actual problem is that these links i use for footer menu using literal control While for top menu i use `aspmenu` control. and literal control for footer menu generates HTML validation error on `http://validator.w3.org/` & i am not sure why same link works for one control & fails for other control for HTML validation

Comment: ERROR MSG `This is usually a cascading error caused by a an undefined entity reference or use of an unencoded ampersand (&) in an URL or body text. See the previous message for further details. ` on http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: You're going to have to capture that issue in the code somewhere.  The semicolon is a reserved character per the RFC spec, so if the ampersand was properly encoded, you wouldn't have an semicolon in the URL.  The issue is that you have HTML in the URL - and that's technically valid but it's not behaving the way you expect it to.  You showed the HTML code for your link below. Can you just remove the HTML and make it a strict & instead?

Comment: Let me know if it works. The only other option is to handle the HTML in the code and try to parse that out, but if you can change the link code to be correct, that's a better solution.

Comment: Just noticed something else.  Your footer code below is calling the value `Language` and your code sample above is looking for `Lang`.  Just make sure they're the same.  Also unrelated, but if that's a stringBuilder that you're using, look into .AppendFormat() as that will save you a ton of overhead in generating that string.

Answer (score 0):

This is because `&amp;` is actually interpreted as the character '&' and not the concatenator.. The query string provided is just not valid.

You could try to decode/parse it with `Server.UrlDecode(queryString)`. And you could try replacing all `&amp;` to '%26' and then feeding it into `Server.UrlDecode` - **but** it's not guaranteed that that will solve the problem.
For more info on `Server.UrlDecode` see MSDN page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6196h3wt(v=vs.110).aspx -

Bottom line is that the queryString is malformed at the moment. If you have control over the code to render the url, then always use `&` and not `&amp;`. (Example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/829138/1155847)

Comment: It Still returns null ` if (HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlDecode(HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString[qValue]) != null)`

Comment: Do you have control over the querystring? It could be that even Server.UrlDecode won't be able to decode it, because it's actually valid to place "&amp;" in the querystring witout it necessarily being intented to be "&"-concatenator.. I guess the querystring is just malformed and you won't be able to fix that.. Where's the URL coming from, where are you getting it from, do you have control of it?

Comment: Thinking out loud & without editor here.. try replacing all "&amp;" values with "%26" (by using [String.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace(v=vs.110).aspx)) and then pass it into Server.UrlDecode.. And see what that gives?

Comment: I generate the url this is the code `for (int i = 0; i < dsMenuFooter.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
{
sbMenuFooter.Append("<a id='footerlink' class='FooterMenuLink' href='" + dsMenuFooter.Tables[0].Rows[i]["PageInternalLinkURL"] + "?PageId=" + dsMenuFooter.Tables[0].Rows[i]["PageId"] + "&amp;Language=" + LangCode + "'>" + dsMenuFooter.Tables[0].Rows[i]["PageName"].ToString().ToUpper() + "</a>");
}`

Comment: just change `&amp;` in your code to `&` as in `"&amp;Language="` to `"&Language="` - otherwise you'll be making a malformed querystring, and no parses for querystrings (even outside .Net) will be able to read it. It should fix your problem.

Comment: It was like that previously.. This is what is frustrating me.. i have tried almost every thing..

Comment: Hmm.. ok. I have no code editor here, myabe try looking in SO for more info >> here's a link http://stackoverflow.com/a/829138/1155847

Answer (score -1):

You need to decode the url prior to attempting to access query string variables...

```
Server.UrlDecode(HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString[qValue])
```

Checkout MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6196h3wt%28v=vs.110%29.aspx