# HttpUtility.UrlEncode using four hexadecimal digits instead of two

Tags: c#, character-encoding, url-encoding

Not sure why, but when I run the following code

```
HtmlAnchor bestellenLink = (HtmlAnchor)e.Item.FindControl("bestellenLink");
var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
var paramValues = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uriBuilder.Query);
paramValues.Add("Test", HttpUtility.UrlEncode("ä"));
uriBuilder.Query = paramValues.ToString();
bestellenLink.HRef = uriBuilder.Uri.ToString();
```

I get the following output in the `bestellenLink.HRef`:

```
http://somedomain/somepage.aspx?Test=%25c3%25a4
```

While the correct URL encoding of "ä" should be `%c3%a4` and not `%25c3%25a4`.
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,
/Francesco

Comment: Might be an issue with the HttpUtility.ParseQueryString?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/829080/how-to-build-a-query-string-for-a-url-in-c#comment16989179_1877016

Comment: Very helpful! I didn't know that... I ended up rewriting the "AppendToQueryString" logic myself without using `ParseQueryString` and now everything works fine!! Thanks!