# Posting to Twitter with C# - single quote returns 401

Tags: c#, twitter, oauth

I developed a small application to post tweets using C#. I followed the below guide and everything works like a charm:

```
http://www.overpie.com/aspnet/articles/csharp-post-message-to-twitter
```

The only problem is that if I try to tweet something having the single quote character('), I get a 401 error. I tried escaping it using all the below, but I either ended up with the same error or the characters.

```
/'
//'
'''
''''
HtmlEncode
```

Any help please? For the record I get the same problem if I tweet with an exclamation mark.

Comment: You need to build Url with classes designed for it like `UriBuilder` and `HttpUtility` (see [Build query string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/829080/how-to-build-a-query-string-for-a-url-in-c) ) for example. Unfortunately you did not provide code that you have, so it is very hard to help you fix it.

Comment: Hi Alexei - the code is exactly as per the URL I linked to.

Comment: With UrlEncode, result in Twitter is: Single%27s+Quote

Comment: For post to be valid SO question it needs to contain *all* related information in the post (source, problem description, what you tried and how it failed). Links to source are ok as supplement.

Comment: `Single%27s+Quote` looks like valid query parameter to me. It is generally good idea to update you question with information you have instead/in addition to comments so it is clear what part of the problem is still a problem and what other people should finally post as "answer".

Answer (score 0):

Can you try escaping through HTML encoding.

```
For single quote use &#39;
```

Comment: Yes, that's one of the ways I tried, forgot to include it in my post. It posts to Twitter but it is displayed just like that &#39;

Comment: Like this: Single&#39;s Quote