# Passing long querystrings over urls shows page not found error(404)

Tags: c#, query-string

I have a "error.aspx" page which is there to mail me if any exception is caught. When I open the page manually, mysite.com/error.aspx, the page opens fine but when it is redirected by a catch block with the exception.message and exception.stackTrace as querystrings, I get an error "page not found". Are the querystrings directing the browser to open a different url? It works fine when run on localhost, though.

```
     public void send_error(Exception ex)
    {
   Response.Redirect("error.aspx?time=" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "&ex=" + ex.Message + "&st=" + ex.StackTrace.Replace("\n", " "), false);

    }
```

Comment: Perhaps exceeding the 2,083 max URL length?

Comment: how long are the strings combined?

Comment: I have set maxQueryStringLength to a long value in web.config

Comment: Side note: I understand that you put very simplified version of constructing query string in the sample. For everyone else who looks at the code - please make sure to encode query parameters - i.e. see [How to build a query string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/829080/how-to-build-a-query-string-for-a-url-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check this [Article](http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/misc/urllength.html), you will see that the max query length of url string is 2048 symbols for Internet explorer. Probably the url is bigger and because of that you have this problem. One solution is to save the desire message in the session as string and after that retrieve it on other pages.

```
string errorMessage = DateTime.Now.ToString() + " " + ex.Message + " " + ex.StackTrace.Replace("\n", " ");
Session["__ErrMessage"] = errorMessage;
```

When you are in other pages you can access this string like this:

```
string errMessage = "";

if(Session["__ErrMessage"] != null)
    errMessage = Session["ErrMessage"].ToString();
```