# Allow plus + sign in URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, url, get, rfc

I am writing a GET calculator for my website. This calculator calculates expressions provided in the `exp` parameter of the URL. I know its against RFC but is there any way I can allow `+` sign in URL?

One way I found was to provide a documentation to my users where they will replace some special tags to add plus sign like `[op:plus]`. This is then replaced by `+` in code behind which a ASP.NET generic handler. But it will be great if there is anything in the RFC that allows `+` sign. So that I don't have to provide any documentation.

Comment: Are your users accessing it through a browser, or programatically, or both?

Comment: @mason Actually, it's a kind of API that can be accessed in any way user like.

Comment: What happens right now if your users enter a + sign?

Comment: @mason asp.net is replacing + with whitespace in URL.

Comment: How are you grabbing the URL? Where's your code?

Comment: @mason I am grabbing the parameter using asp.net Request object `Request["exp"].ToString()`

Comment: What about if you use `Request.RawUrl`?

Comment: @mason Yeah its showing + in that

Comment: So write your own methods to parse your operations out of `Request.RawUrl`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proper way to encode a `+` sign in a URL query string parameter is `%2B`. ASP.NET will automatically decode this as `+` for you.

If your users use [a proper URL encoding library](https://stackoverflow.com/q/829080/87698), this encoding will happen automatically:

```
string equation = "1 + 2 - 3";
Console.WriteLine(HttpUtility.UrlEncode(equation));
```

Output:

> 1+%2b+2+-+3

Comment: ok but asp.net is replacing `+` with whitespace in URL. Your string will be like `1 2 - 3`.

Comment: @ErikPhilips how can I use this when getting parameter using `Request["exp"]`? it replaces `+` with whitespace.

Comment: @AishwaryaShiva: The point is: If the user wants to call your service with the value `1 + 2 - 3`, he should call it like this: `http://example.com/yourService?exp=1+%2b+2+-+3`. Then you get the correct value. If he calls it like this: `http://example.com/yourService?exp=1+2-3`, he violates the RFC (he transmits an encoded space instead of an encoded plus sign).

Comment: @Heinzi Yeah that is the same problem that I mentioned in the question. User must know `%2B` is plus or my own rule `[op:plus]`. Ok I realized now that we cannot go against RFC. But there must be a rule in RFC which will allow anything enclosed in double quotes. Can you provide me with the RFC link where using directions of `+` sign is written?

Comment: @AishwaryaShiva: *But there must be a rule in RFC which will allow anything enclosed in double quotes.* Nope. This is not about "allowing", it's about "encoding". That's like saying *"but there must be a rule in morse code that allows me to transmit something else than dots and dashes if I enclose it in double dashes"*. Dots and dashes in morse code are just something different that dots and dashes in English language. Likewise, `+`, `&`, `=` in a URL are something different that the *actual values* `+`, `&`, `=`. ...

Comment: ...It just happens that, by mere coincidence, `abc` in a URL also means `abc` in data. But that's just it: A coincidence. You (and your users) need to properly encode everything you use in a URL. Just like a morse code user needs to know that `A` equals dot-dash, a URL user must know that `+` equals `%2B`.