# ADO.net SqlParameter using a + sign between words

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I am using ADO.net and using `SqlParameter` passing into a stored procedure a group of words that sometimes may have a `+` between then. Up until the plus sign the search is working fine but once I add it I am getting no results. Do I need to change anything in the c# code I am run the sp fine with the plus sign.

c# code

```
SqlParameter[] parms = new SqlParameter[] {
    new SqlParameter("@Title", SqlDbType.VarChar)
};
parms[0].Value =Title;
```

SQL SP

```
create PROCEDURE [usp_Select_Title] -
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here  
@Title nvarchar(512) = null




WHERE (dcc.Title like '%'+ @Title +'%')
```

Comment: Is that stored procedure doing anything with that @TItle that might trip?

Comment: Its just doing a like I can run in from management studio and it runs fine

Comment: Are trying to pass in _multiple_ titles in one parameter, or you are trying to search for a title with a plus sign in it?

Comment: trying to search for one title with a plus sign &title=Red + Blue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the discussion in comment, the value was passed to via query string in URL. In this the case the + sign has a semantic meaning in the query string which is used to represent a space.

So, the solution for this is to encode the + sign with `%2B` in URL and decode back to + in C#.

References:

- [Allow plus + sign in URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30262783/allow-plus-sign-in-url)
- [Plus sign in query string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6855624/plus-sign-in-query-string)

Comment: I did try that but I am still not getting the data being returned

Comment: can it be related to the SQL WHERE Clause

Comment: Can you put debugger and check what value is going to SP.

Comment: in sql profiler its removing the + sign

Comment: So, you need to replace your + sign with unicode from ado.net and replace back in sp

Comment: sorry so it looks like postman is removing the plus

Comment: @Jefferson can you create executable demo in https://dotnetfiddle.net/  and http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: @Jefferson are you passing your parameter from URL?

Comment: I'm not 100% it's the same, but anytime I've used `SqlParamter` I've used three parameters - Parameter Name, SqlDbType and Size: `"@Title", SqlDbType.NVarChar, -1` (-1 for max). Could that be your issue?

Comment: Yes I am passing the parameter from a URL in postman.

Comment: @Jefferson I think that is your issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30262783/allow-plus-sign-in-url
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6855624/plus-sign-in-query-string