# Jira Rest Api JQL isnt working using &

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api

Iam using the Jira Rest Api to read data from our Jira-System. In most cases this works fine but i have a problem if *&* is in query.

I try following query:

http://jira-test.meinServer.de/rest/api/2/search?jql=labels="F&E"

which produces this error message:

"Fehler in der JQL-Abfrage: Die Zeichenfolge mit Anführungszeichen 'F' wurde nicht abgeschlossen. (Zeile 1, Zeichen 8)"

in englisch:
"Error in JQL-Syntax: The string with 'F' isn't closed. (line 1, char 8)"

I found that *&* is the problem. But i can't find some workaround or documentation how to escape this.

Someone got a solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't encode your query string properly. Try: http://jira-test.meinServer.de/rest/api/2/search?jql=labels%3D%22F%26E%22

**Reference**

The part of an [URI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier) caught between `?` and `#` characters is called the **query string** (the part after `#` is called **fragment**). Often the query is a sequence of key–value pairs (laid out as `{key}={value}`) separated with the `&` character.

If you analyze the URL you provided and split it by `&` you'll see that in fact you are passing two parameters in your query string:

- parameter `jql` with a value of `labels="F`
- parameter `E"` with no value

The second parameter is ignored as this particular REST endpoint doesn't expect it. As you can now clearly see you are passing a malformed JQL in your URL. It's because you want to include a special character in your JQL query.

To make it possible you have to properly encode your JQL. This is a common problem and most of the platforms provide tools to do that. Here are examples for [JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332872/encode-url-in-javascript), [C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/829080/how-to-build-a-query-string-for-a-url-in-c) and [Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786042/java-url-encoding-of-query-string-parameters).

[Click here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) to learn more about the query strings.