# Create Query String From Query Results

Tags: c#, asp.net, query-string

In `C#` I want to run a SQL Query and parse the results into a `QueryString` to pass to a web page.  In my testing I am trying to do this, but I get an error of

> Key already exists

What is incorrect or what is the correct way to do this?

```
private void PrepQuery()
{
    Dictionary<string, string> dictFormValues = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    string connectionString = null;
    SqlConnection cnn;
    SqlCommand cmd;
    StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
    SqlDataReader reader;
    connectionString = "Data Source=server;Initial Catalog=database;User ID=;Password=";
    sql.Append("select employeename, employeeaddress, employeezip, employeecity, employeestate, employeephone ");
    sql.Append("from abcd ");
    sql.Append("where validated is not null ");
    cnn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    try
    {
        cnn.Open();
        cmd = new SqlCommand(sql.ToString(), cnn);
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            dictFormValues.Add("employeename", reader.GetValue(0).ToString());
            dictFormValues.Add("employeeaddress", reader.GetValue(1).ToString());
            dictFormValues.Add("employeezip", reader.GetValue(2).ToString());
            dictFormValues.Add("employeecity", reader.GetValue(3).ToString());
            dictFormValues.Add("employeestate", reader.GetValue(4).ToString());
            dictFormValues.Add("employeephone", reader.GetValue(5).ToString());
            name = reader.GetValue(0).ToString();
        }
        reader.Close();
        cmd.Dispose();
        cnn.Close();
    }
    bool success = false;
    success = FormatForWebAPI();
    if (success = true; { GenerateEmail(); 
    if (sucess = false;) { ShowErrorOnScreen(); }
}

private void FormatForWebAPI();
{
    string strEndpointURL = string.Format("http://requestb.in/pm9rstuv/"); 
    System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer json = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
    foreach (var d in dictFormValues) { strPostData += d.Key + "=" + Server.UrlEncode(d.Value) + "&"; }
    strPostData += "hs_context=";
    System.Net.HttpWebRequest r = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create(strEndpointURL);
    r.Method = "POST";
    r.Accept = "application/json";
    r.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    r.ContentLength = strPostData.Length;
    r.KeepAlive = false;
    using (System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(r.GetRequestStream())) 
    { 
            try { sw.Write(strPostData); }
            catch { return false; }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Looks like there are duplicates in your data. Dictionarys don't allow duplicate keys. Any particular reason why you're using a Dictionary instead of perhaps a list of tuples (see here: http://www.dotnetperls.com/tuple)?

Comment: @FunFlyWhiteGuy are you missing a `catch` block

Comment: You loop the result, so if there are n rows you try to add n keys with the name `employeename` which is not allowed. See [How to build a query string for a URL in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/829080/how-to-build-a-query-string-for-a-url-in-c)

Comment: @sr28 - I have never used a tuple, thank you for the link I will take a look

Comment: @FunFlyWhiteGuy - that's just a suggestion. It may well be better to create your own 'employee' class with properties for all the info you want to store and create a list of those (see my answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically Dictionaries don't allow duplicate keys. From [MSDN - Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Every key in a Dictionary must be unique according to
>   the dictionary's equality comparer.

In your case you are adding 'employeename', 'employeeaddress' etc as keys to your dictionary. So by the looks of it, if you expect to have more than 1 employee (or row of data) then you will get this error, as for each 1 it will try and add the same keys again (employeename etc.)

As per my comment try using [Tuples](http://www.dotnetperls.com/tuple) such as a `List<tuple<string, string>>`. There are various other ways to store data, which contains duplicates such as in a [DataTable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or perhaps in an xml document. It really depends on what you plan to do with it once you've got it really.

Alternatively create your own class of type 'employee' that contains properties for all the info you want to store (name, address, zipcode etc) and then create a list of those, like `List<employee>`.

Comment: I want to return the values and format them as a query string so I can send to a web page API

Comment: @FunFlyWhiteGuy - I would probably go with creating your own class of employee then and creating a list.