# replace the matched expression from string and its next charecter?POST operation

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, string

i have a string suppose that one

```
  http://www.whitelabelhosting.co.uk/flight-search.php?dept=any&journey=R&DepTime=0900
```

and now what i am doing is here in c sharp

```
       string linkmain = link.Replace("&DepTime=", "&DepTime=" + journey);
```

but the time is being added as 09000900

and in case of

```
   string linkmain =   link.Replace("Journey=", "Journey="+journey);
```

journey added as RR

so i have to get the value of R that is after Journer=? AND deptTime=?

that are not same every time so how to get them during replace as they are present just after where  ? sign is marked

**this is a post operation so parameter are different like**

journey :

R

M

O

and time :

0900 , 1200 , 0400

Comment: I have edited your question so it can actually be understood.

Comment: no you donot understand actually `Journey=` is same in string every time but its next value that is `R` will be different so we have to replace `R` but we donot actually now is this R or O or M depends upon journey so we now its value that is `JOURNEY=??`

Comment: It doesn't matter which query string parameter your question is about, the principle remains the same. Do you understand your current question is very unreadable and hard to understand, and that my edit made it actually answerable? Is it a possibility that you don't know what you're doing, and that you don't understand the edit?

Comment: There are built in classes to handle query strings, doing this with `RegEx` is just making this harder than it has to be.  [This question may help you.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/829080/how-to-build-a-query-string-for-a-url-in-c)

Comment: Wait so you expected to take a string like 'www.website.com?foo=bar' and replace 'foo=' with something and it update 'bar' using some magic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to try out the following regex. [Regex101 link](https://regex101.com/r/dU8zK9/1)

```
((?:\?.*?&|\?)journey=)[^&]*
```

Try out the following code to replace the value of journey to `replacement`

```
string url = "http://www.whitelabelhosting.co.uk/flight-search.php?dept=any&journey=R&DepTime=0900";
string newUrl = Regex.Replace(url, @"((?:\?.*?&|\?)journey=)[^&]*", "$1"+"replacement");
```

Remember to add the following to your file:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

You can do the same for `DepTime` using the following regex:

```
((?:\?.*?&|\?)DepTime=)[^&]*
```

Comment: char rep = linkmain[94];

Answer (score 2):

Use HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(url) with will return a NameValueCollection. You can then loop this collection to manipulate the data how you want and build the new url from that.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150046(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: This is the proper way to do it