# How to properly change URL parameters?

Tags: c#, url

First let me explain what I mean by properly: I found many methods out there, but most of them will end up using string manipulations and things like that. I'd like to know if there is a simple way to do such using built in functions.

So far I change the parameters of a `URL` with a `string myNewValue`:

```
Uri myUri = new Uri(URL);
var qs = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(myUri.Query);
qs["ParameterName"] = myNewValue;
```

This does work pretty well. Now I'd like to get my `URL` back in a `string` with those new parameters. What is the proper way to do it? Something like getting the `URL` without patterns from my original string and merging the obtained parameters?

**Note:** So far I'm able to do it with `Substring` and such, I just find it "**unclean**" when one start to find chars in a string to `Substring` stuff from it.

How I do is simple. From my original URL I substring up to the "`?`", then I combine with `qs.ToString()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the `UriBuilder` class offer enough power to you? It doesn't do everything (in particular, it doesn't build paths) but the missing bits are easy to fill in. For example, the default `ToString` of `KeyValuePair<string, string>` works well with `string.Join()`:

```
var myUri = new Uri(url);
var qs = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(myUri.Query);
qs["param1"] = "newVal1";

var path = string.Join("&", qs); // UriBuilder can't do this bit for you
// But it can put the bits back together and look after oddities,
// slashes, url encoding, etc.
var builder = new UriBuilder(myUri) {Path = path};
var newUri = builder.Uri;
```

For extra tidiness in your code, this could be wrapped up in an extension method like this:

```
public static Uri SetAttribute(this Uri uri, string key, string value) {
  var qs = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uri.Query);
  qs[key] = value;
  return new UriBuilder(myUri) {Path = string.Join("&", qs)}.Uri;
}
```

Now the original code becomes:

```
Uri myUri = new Uri(URL);
myUri.SetAttribute("ParameterName") = myNewValue;
```

Comment: thanks!! I prefer it than me method. Too bad there isn't a class that does it all... I think that replacing parameter from a URL is common stuff...

Comment: Yes, it is, but I suppose that they chose not do duplicate the functionality of `string.Join()` and `KeyValuePair.ToString()`. You could add a trivial extension method to `Uri` to do it for you.

Comment: I've just been browsing through the solutions in [this popular question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/829080/3195526). I can only assume that `UrlBuilder` did not exist at the time those answers were written. In particular, the comments on the question suggest that it didn't exist in 2013.