# C# HttpWebRequest pass object as post data params

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, serialization, httpwebrequest

I am sending HttpWebRequest(post ) to some api services.

Here is a code example :
This is the post data params :

```
var postData = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    {
        "OtherBankNames",
        dto.OtherBankNames
    },
    {
        "AccountOpeningMainReasonId",
        dto.AccountOpeningMainReasonId?.ToString()
    },
    {
        "ActivityCategoryId",
        dto.ActivityCategoryId?.ToString()
    },

    {
        "ActivitySubCategoryId",
        dto.ActivitySubCategoryId?.ToString()
    },

    {
        "AnnualTurnoverSalaryRateId",
        dto.AnnualTurnoverSalaryRateId?.ToString()
    },
...
```

`dto` is just a class  `ChatInfoDto`.

Data passed correctly like this :

`OtherBankNames=value&AccountOpeningMainReasonId=value... etc.`

I have a helper method which converts `postData` Dictionary like query params :

```
public static string BuildPostTPayload(Dictionary<string, string> keyValuePairs)
{
    if (keyValuePairs.Count == 0)
        return null;

    var temp = keyValuePairs.Select(x => x.Key + "=" + System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(x.Value));
    var result = string.Join("&", temp);

    return result;
}
```

Everything works fine , I am just curious to know :  is it possible to serialize object as a post params and not write each property manually  like I do in Dictionary case?

So what I need is a magic method which serialize the whole T(generic class)   like a query params

Comment: Did you try using a `NameValueCollection`? https://stackoverflow.com/a/1877016/2707705

Comment: Thanks for that link. WIth Dictionary I am doing almost the same. Class is huge and create that dictionary is tedious process

Comment: @user3857731 you can use reflection to inspect the object and create either the dictionary or the query string directly