# How to mimic with a c# http request an ajax call which apparently sends a JavaScript array of objects to server

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, http, request

I am not familiar with JavaScript and i am trying to mimic the following ajax POST in C# (OWNER option from http://api-examples.petexec.net/)

```
var baseUrl = 'https://beta.petexec.net/api';
var access_token = '';//Your access token @see: https://beta.petexec.net/api/apidoc/index.html#api-Authenticate-GetToken
$('#submitButton').on('click', addOwner);

function addOwner(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var formData = $('#addOwnerForm').serializeArray();

    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : baseUrl + '/owner/',
        dataType : 'json',
        data : formData,
        headers : {
            'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + access_token
        },
        success : successCallback,
        error : errorCallback
    });
}

function successCallback(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    $('#result').html(textStatus + '<br/>' + JSON.stringify(data));
}

function errorCallback(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    $('#result').html(JSON.stringify(jqXHR.responseJSON));
}



$("#select_all").change(function() {
    $("input:checkbox").prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked"));
});
```

The JSON.stringify is not applied to "formData", so I am not sure what the server is expecting to receive.

Also, since there are no ContentType it seems like the ContentType is application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8.

I have tried to generate the data in C# in different formats and have not being able to successfully execute the request.

If i try the ajax call it executes successfully. 
Below is part of the c# code,

```
    public static string AddOwner(AuthenticateResponseModel authenticateData, OwnerModel owner, string json)
    {
        string _methodName = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType + "-" + MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name;
        string _retVal = string.Empty;

        // Related to HTTP objects.
        WebRequest _restRequest;
        WebResponse _restResponse;

        // Related to JSON serialization
        //JavaScriptSerializer _jsonSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

        // Authenticate and retrieve the session token.
        try
        {
            //byte[] _encbuff = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Constants.CLIENT_ID + ":" + Constants.CLIENT_SECRET);
            //string _encbase = Convert.ToBase64String(_encbuff);

            string _request = string.Format("{{\"username\":\"{0}\",\"password\":\"{1}\",\"password2\":\"{2}\",\"firstname\":\"{3}\",\"lastName\":\"{4}\"" +
               ",\"employer\":\"{5}\",\"addr1\":\"{6}\",\"addr2\":\"{7}\",\"city\":\"{8}\",\"state\":\"{9}\",\"zip\":\"{10}\",\"email\":\"{11}\"" +
               ",\"homePhone\":\"{12}\",\"cellPhone\":\"{13}\",\"workPhone\":\"{14}\",\"emergencyContact\":\"{15}\",\"emergencyPhone\":\"{16}\",\"emergencyEmail\":\"{17}\",\"howFoundId\":\"{18}\"" +
               ",\"howFoundOther\":\"{19}\",\"additionalOwner\":\"{20}\",\"birthdayEmail\":\"{21}\",\"boardingEmail\":\"{22}\",\"boardingReminderEmail\":\"{23}\",\"daycarePackageEmail\":\"{24}\",\"enableEmail\":\"{25}\"" +
               ",\"groomingEmail\":\"{26}\",\"newOwnerEmail\":\"{27}\",\"orderReceiptEmail\":\"{28}\",\"scheduledServiceEmail\":\"{29}\",\"trainingClassEmail\":\"{30}\",\"temptestEmail\":\"{31}\",\"vaccinationEmail\":\"{32}\"" +
               ",\"cardName\":\"{33}\",\"cardHolder\":\"{34}\",\"cardNum\":\"{35}\",\"expMonth\":\"{36}\",\"expYear\":\"{37}\",\"billingName\":\"{38}\",\"billingAddr1\":\"{39}\"" +
               ",\"billingAddr2\":\"{40}\",\"billingCity\":\"{41}\",\"billingState\":\"{42}\",\"billingZip\":\"{43}\",\"isPrimary\":\"{44}\"}}",

            //string _request = string.Format("[{{\"name\":\"username\", \"value\":\"{0}\"}},{{\"name\":\"password\",\"value\":\"{1}\"}},{{\"name\":\"password2\",\"value\":\"{2}\"}},{{\"name\":\"firstName\",\"value:\":\"{3}\"}},{{\"name\":\"lastName\",\"value\":\"{4}\"}}" +
            //     ",{{\"name\":\"employer\", \"value\":\"{5}\"}},{{\"name\":\"addr1\",\"value\":\"{6}\"}},{{\"name\":\"addr2\",\"value\":\"{7}\"}},{{\"name\":\"city\",\"value:\":\"{8}\"}},{{\"name\":\"state\",\"value:\":\"{9}\"}},{{\"name\":\"zip\",\"value\":\"{10}\"}},{{\"name\":\"email\", \"value\":\"{11}\"}}" +
            //     ",{{\"name\":\"homePhone\", \"value\":\"{12}\"}},{{\"name\":\"cellPhone\",\"value\":\"{13}\"}},{{\"name\":\"workPhone\",\"value\":\"{14}\"}},{{\"name\":\"emergencyContact\",\"value:\":\"{15}\"}},{{\"name\":\"emergencyPhone\",\"value:\":\"{16}\"}},{{\"name\":\"emergencyEmail\",\"value\":\"{17}\"}},{{\"name\":\"howFoundID\",\"value\":\"{18}\"}}" +
            //     ",{{\"name\":\"howFoundOther\", \"value\":\"{19}\"}},{{\"name\":\"additionalOwner\",\"value\":\"{20}\"}},{{\"name\":\"birthdayEmail\",\"value\":\"{21}\"}},{{\"name\":\"boardingEmail\",\"value:\":\"{22}\"}},{{\"name\":\"boardingReminderEmail\",\"value:\":\"{23}\"}},{{\"name\":\"daycarePackageEmail\",\"value\":\"{24}\"}},{{\"name\":\"enableEmail\",\"value\":\"{25}\"}}" +
            //     ",{{\"name\":\"groomingEmail\", \"value\":\"{26}\"}},{{\"name\":\"newOwnerEmail\",\"value\":\"{27}\"}},{{\"name\":\"orderReceiptEmail\",\"value\":\"{28}\"}},{{\"name\":\"scheduledServiceEmail\",\"value:\":\"{29}\"}},{{\"name\":\"trainingClassEmail\",\"value:\":\"{30}\"}},{{\"name\":\"temptestEmail\",\"value\":\"{31}\"}},{{\"name\":\"vaccinationEmail\",\"value\":\"{32}\"}}" +
            //     ",{{\"name\":\"cardName\", \"value\":\"{33}\"}},{{\"name\":\"cardHolder\",\"value\":\"{34}\"}},{{\"name\":\"cardNum\",\"value\":\"{35}\"}},{{\"name\":\"expMonth\",\"value:\":\"{36}\"}},{{\"name\":\"expYear\",\"value:\":\"{37}\"}},{{\"name\":\"billingName\",\"value\":\"{38}\"}},{{\"name\":\"billingAddr1\",\"value\":\"{39}\"}}" +
            //     ",{{\"name\":\"billingAddr2\", \"value\":\"{40}\"}},{{\"name\":\"billingCity\",\"value\":\"{41}\"}},{{\"name\":\"billingState\",\"value\":\"{42}\"}},{{\"name\":\"billingZip\",\"value:\":\"{43}\"}},{{\"name\":\"isPrimary\",\"value:\":\"{44}\"}}]",

            //string _request = json;

            owner.username, owner.password, owner.password2, owner.firstName, owner.lastName, 
                owner.employer, owner.addr1, owner.addr2, owner.city, owner.state, owner.zip, owner.email, 
                owner.homePhone, owner.cellPhone, owner.workPhone, owner.emergencyContact, owner.emergencyPhone, owner.emergencyEmail, owner.howFoundID, 
                owner.howFoundOther, owner.additionalOwner, owner.birthdayEmail, owner.boardingEmail, owner.boardingReminderEmail, owner.daycarePackageEmail, owner.enableEmail, 
                owner.groomingEmail, owner.newOwnerEmail, owner.orderReceiptEmail, owner.scheduledServiceEmail, owner.trainingClassEmail, owner.temptestEmail, owner.vaccinationEmail,
                owner.cardName, owner.cardHolder, owner.cardNum, owner.expMonth, owner.expYear, owner.billingName, owner.billingAddr1, 
                owner.billingAddr2, owner.billingCity, owner.billingState, owner.billingZip, owner.isPrimary); // Parameters for the request.


            string _uri = Constants.BASE_URI + "/owner/";

            _restRequest = WebRequest.Create(_uri);  // Set the URI for the request to be made. 
            _restRequest.Method = Constants.VERB_METHOD_POST; // Set the http verb.
            _restRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"; // Constants.JSON_CONTENT_TYPE; // Set the content type.
            _restRequest.Headers[Constants.HTTP_SESSION_TOKEN_HEADER] = "Bearer " + authenticateData.access_token; 

            //CustomLog(_methodName, "Request to be sent for username, " + username);

            using (Stream requestStream = _restRequest.GetRequestStream())
            {
                byte[] inputStringBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_request);
                requestStream.Write(inputStringBytes, 0, inputStringBytes.Length);
            }
            //CustomLog(_methodName, "Request sent");

            using (_restResponse = _restRequest.GetResponse())
            {
                // Get the response stream.
                using (Stream _responseStream = _restResponse.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    // Read the response stream from the httpheader.
                    StreamReader _rdr = new StreamReader(_responseStream, Encoding.UTF8);
                    string _rawJsonAddOwnerResponse = _rdr.ReadToEnd();

                    // verify that it returned a result.
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_rawJsonAddOwnerResponse))
                        throw new Exception("Session token was not created. No result returned from request to logon. username: " + owner.username  + " userEmail = " + owner.email);

                    AddOwnerResponse _authResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AddOwnerResponse>(_rawJsonAddOwnerResponse);


                    // verify that the result isn’t empty.
                    if (_authResponse.success == "false")
                        throw new Exception("Unable to create owner. username: " + owner.username + " userEmail = " + owner.email);

                    // Check if request was successfully responded.
                    HttpWebResponse _response = (HttpWebResponse)_restResponse;
                    if (_response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                    {
                        //CustomLog(_methodName, "Owner with username: " + owner.username + ", userEmail = " + owner.email + " was successfully created. Session token: " + authenticateData.access_token + " message: " + authenticateData.message);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //CustomLog(_methodName, "Owner with username: " + owner.username + ", userEmail = " + owner.email + " was not created. Session token: " + authenticateData.access_token + " message: " + authenticateData.message);
                    }
                }
            }
            //CustomLog(_methodName, "Response received");
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            //CustomLog(_methodName, "Exception: " + ex.Message);
        }

        return _retVal;
    }
```

I have also tried to JsonConvert.SerializeObject(owner);
and create a list of NameValue custom type and serializing as well,
                List _nameValueLst = new List();

```
            _nameValueLst.Add(new NameValue()
            {
                name = "username",
                value = owner.username
            });

            _nameValueLst.Add(new NameValue()
            {
                name = "password",
                value = owner.password
            });

            _nameValueLst.Add(new NameValue()
            {
                name = "password2",
                value = owner.password2
            });

            _nameValueLst.Add(new NameValue()
            {
                name = "firstName",
                value = owner.firstName
            });

            _nameValueLst.Add(new NameValue()
            {
                name = "lastName",
                value = owner.lastName
            });

            _nameValueLst.Add(new NameValue()
            {
                name = "employer",
                value = owner.employer
            });

            _nameValueLst.Add(new NameValue()
            {
                name = "addr1",
                value = owner.addr1
            });

            _nameValueLst.Add(new NameValue()
            {
                name = "addr2",
                value = owner.addr2
            });

            _nameValueLst.Add(new NameValue()
            {
                name = "city",
                value = owner.city
            });

            _nameValueLst.Add(new NameValue()
            {
                name = "state",
                value = owner.state
            });

            _nameValueLst.Add(new NameValue()
            {
                name = "zip",
                value = owner.zip.ToString()
            });

            _nameValueLst.Add(new NameValue()
            {
                name = "email",
                value = owner.email
            });

            _nameValueLst.Add(new NameValue()
            {
                name = "homePhone",
                value = owner.homePhone

            });
            _nameValueLst.Add(new NameValue()
            {
                name = "cellPhone",
                value = owner.cellPhone
            });

            _nameValueLst.Add(new NameValue()
            {
                name = "workPhone",
                value = owner.workPhone
            });

            _nameValueLst.Add(new NameValue()
            {
                name = "emergencyContact",
                value = owner.emergencyContact
            });

            _nameValueLst.Add(new NameValue()
            {
                name = "emergencyPhone",
                value = owner.emergencyPhone
            });

            _nameValueLst.Add(new NameValue()
            {
                name = "emergencyEmail",
                value = owner.emergencyEmail
            });

            _nameValueLst.Add(new NameValue()
            {
                name = "howFoundId",
                value = owner.howFoundID.ToString()
            });

            _nameValueLst.Add(new NameValue()
            {
                name = "howFoundOther",
                value = owner.howFoundOther
            });

            _nameValueLst.Add(new NameValue()
            {
                name = "additionalOwner",
                value = owner.additionalOwner
            });

            _nameValueLst.Add(new NameValue()
            {
                name = "birthdayEmail",
                value = owner.birthdayEmail.ToString()
            });

            _nameValueLst.Add(new NameValue()
            {
                name = "boardingEmail",
                value = owner.boardingEmail.ToString()
            });

            _nameValueLst.Add(new NameValue()
            {
                name = "boardingReminderEmail",
                value = owner.boardingReminderEmail.ToString()
            });

            _nameValueLst.Add(new NameValue()
            {
                name = "daycarePackageEmail",
                value = owner.daycarePackageEmail.ToString()
            });

            _nameValueLst.Add(new NameValue()
            {
                name = "enableEmail",
                value = owner.enableEmail.ToString()
            });

            _nameValueLst.Add(new NameValue()
            {
                name = "groomingEmail",
                value = owner.groomingEmail.ToString()
            });

            _nameValueLst.Add(new NameValue()
            {
                name = "newOwnerEmail",
                value = owner.newOwnerEmail.ToString()
            });

            _nameValueLst.Add(new NameValue()
            {
                name = "orderReceiptEmail",
                value = owner.orderReceiptEmail.ToString()
            });

            _nameValueLst.Add(new NameValue()
            {
                name = "scheduledServiceEmail",
                value = owner.scheduledServiceEmail.ToString()
            });


            _nameValueLst.Add(new NameValue()
            {
                name = "trainingClassEmail",
                value = owner.trainingClassEmail.ToString()
            });

            _nameValueLst.Add(new NameValue()
            {
                name = "temptestEmail",
                value = owner.temptestEmail.ToString()
            });
            _nameValueLst.Add(new NameValue()
            {
                name = "vaccinationEmail",
                value = owner.vaccinationEmail.ToString()
            });
            _nameValueLst.Add(new NameValue()
            {
                name = "cardName",
                value = owner.cardName.ToString()
            });
            _nameValueLst.Add(new NameValue()
            {
                name = "cardHolder",
                value = owner.cardHolder.ToString()
            });

            _nameValueLst.Add(new NameValue()
            {
                name = "cardNum",
                value = owner.cardNum.ToString()
            });
            _nameValueLst.Add(new NameValue()
            {
                name = "expMonth",
                value = owner.expMonth.ToString()
            });

            _nameValueLst.Add(new NameValue()
            {
                name = "expYear",
                value = owner.expYear.ToString()
            });

            _nameValueLst.Add(new NameValue()
            {
                name = "billingName",
                value = owner.billingName.ToString()
            });

            _nameValueLst.Add(new NameValue()
            {
                name = "billingAddr1",
                value = owner.billingAddr1.ToString()
            });

            _nameValueLst.Add(new NameValue()
            {
                name = "billingAddr2",
                value = owner.billingAddr2.ToString()
            });

            _nameValueLst.Add(new NameValue()
            {
                name = "billingCity",
                value = owner.billingCity.ToString()
            });

            _nameValueLst.Add(new NameValue()
            {
                name = "billingState",
                value = owner.billingState.ToString()
            });

            _nameValueLst.Add(new NameValue()
            {
                name = "billingZip",
                value = owner.billingZip.ToString()
            });

            _nameValueLst.Add(new NameValue()
            {
                name = "isPrimary",
                value = owner.isPrimary.ToString()
            });

            string _request = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_nameValueLst);
```

The response I get is,

{"success":false,"errors":["Please enter a first name.","Please enter a last name.","Please enter an address.","Please enter a city name.","Please enter a state.","Please enter a ZIP code.","Please enter a cell number for the owner.","Please enter an emergency contact.","Please enter the emergency contact phone number.","Please enter a valid email address."]}

I am clearly passing these values and their casing matches that of the online documentation (adding owner), https://secure.petexec.net/api/apidoc/index.html#api-Authorization-AuthorizationToken

I believe the data is being passed incorrectly and it is not being recognized.

Does anybody knows what is the correct way to mimic that ajax POST request?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the desired format expected by the server is "key=value&key=value" therefore the Json object I tried to send was not working.

Here is how I am creating the string,

```
            var _nameValueLst = (from data in owner.GetType().GetProperties() select new { name = data.Name, value = data.GetValue(owner, null) }).ToList();
            NameValueCollection _myCollection = new NameValueCollection();

            foreach (var item in _nameValueLst)
            {
                _myCollection.Add(item.name, item.value.ToString());
            }

            string _request = ToQueryString(_myCollection);
```

From [How to build a query string for a URL in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/829080/how-to-build-a-query-string-for-a-url-in-c?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top)

```
    private static string ToQueryString(NameValueCollection nvc)
    {
        var array = (from key in nvc.AllKeys
                     from value in nvc.GetValues(key)
                     select string.Format("{0}={1}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(key), HttpUtility.UrlEncode(value)))
            .ToArray();
        return "?" + string.Join("&", array);
    }
```