# compose a query URL string

Tags: c#

I am searching for a construction to build a method in (C#) for construct a query URL based on Dictionary list. The solution I build didn't matched with the output I want. Does someone I better idea?

```
public string querystring()
{
    //start with ? 
    var startPosition = string.Join("?", availiblebalance.FirstOrDefault().Key + "=" + availiblebalance.FirstOrDefault().Value);
    //var removeElement = startPosition.Split('='); availiblebalance.Remove(removeElement[0]); 
    var otherPostions = string.Join("&", availiblebalance.Select(x => x.Key + "=" + x.Value).ToArray());

    var result = string.Format("{0}{1}", startPosition,otherPostions);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: `The solution I build didn't matched with the output I want` - you might want to tell us what you *do* want!

Comment: Is this answer of any use? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/829080/how-to-build-a-query-string-for-a-url-in-c
Or maybe this article http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/Network/DictionaryToQueryString.htm

Comment: I suspect you're missing `HttpUtility.UrlEncode`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building a query string from a dictionary should be fairly straightforward - you dont need to treat the start position and the rest of the params separately.

```
var queryString = "?" + String.Join("&", 
          myDictionary.Select(kv => String.Concat(kv.Key,"=",kv.Value)));
```

You may need to `UrlEncode` the values, depending on what they contain.

Answer (score 0):

There is an `HttpUtility` that allows you to build the query string.

```
var queryString = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);
foreach (var entry in myDictionary)
    queryString[entry.Key] = entry.Value;

return "?" + queryString.ToString();
```