# Remove one query param value

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

Is it possible to remove 1 query param value in a simple way? (I'm thinking about recreating the list of values without the value we want to remove using `RouteValueDictionary` and `IUrlHelper.ActionContext.HttpContext.Request.Query` but I'm hoping there is a simpler way).

Example:

Original query: `localhost:5555/search?cat=none&cat=cat1&cat=cat2`

Wanted query (removing cat1): `localhost:5555/search?cat=none&cat=cat2`

Comment: Where in the Asp.Net pipeline do you expect this to occur?

Comment: @Amy I don't understand your question.

Comment: Do you know what the Asp.Net pipeline *is*?

Comment: Nope. Do I need to know what it is to do a "simple" task like this?

Comment: The answer depends on when you expect this to occur.  You can write an Owin middleware, use a Web API action filter, use a Web API delegating handler, do it in a Web API controller itself... how you do it can affect everything hosted in Owin, or just Web API, or Web API and some other set of components.

Comment: Oh, now I understand. I want to use it in a controller (I'm doing a filter system and I want to remove a certain filter from the query).

Answer (score 2):

One way of doing this inside a controller's action method would be to do the following:

```
var queryParms = Request.GetQueryNameValuePairs();
```

[`GetQueryNameValuePairs` is an extension method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httprequestmessageextensions.getquerynamevaluepairs(v=vs.118).aspx) found in the System.Net.Http namespace.

`queryParms` is an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>>`.  To filter it you can use some LINQ:

```
var queryParms = Request
    .GetQueryNameValuePairs()
    .Where(kvp => kvp.Key != "excluded key");
```

To filter by key/value pair:

```
var queryParms = Request
    .GetQueryNameValuePairs()
    .Where(kvp => kvp.Key != "excluded key" && kvp.Value != "excluded value");
```

This gives you a list of key/value pairs excluding the undesired query parameter.  If you wanted to exclude a list of keys, you can use the following variation of the above:

```
var excludedKeys = new[] { "excluded a", "excluded b", "etc" };
var queryParms = Request
    .GetQueryNameValuePairs()
    .Where(kvp => !excludedKeys.Contains(kvp.Key));
```

If you need to *change* or *replace* a query parameter value:

```
var queryParms = Request.GetQueryNameValuePairs();
var cat = queryParms.FirstOrDefault(x=> x.Key == "cat");
if (cat != null && cat.Value == "cat1")
{
    cat.Value = "none";
}
// other stuff with query parms
```

Once you have your query parameters the way you want them, you'll need to reconstruct the URL.  For this I turn you to a very good answer to another question:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1877016/47589

Comment: This removes the whole query param, if you look at my example I only want to remove one specific value (the cat1 in the example out of the none, cat1, cat2.

Comment: Change it to filter by `Value`, then.  The general principal is the same.

Comment: Thanks but how would I then use this to reconstruct the url?

Comment: Use the `Uri` class (or the `UriBuilder` class), but why would you want to do that?

Comment: Because I'm making a Filter system and if the user wants to remove a filter i'll remove it from the query

Comment: We've already removed it from the query.  Why reconstruct a new URL?

Comment: Well because i'll use it in an <a> element. Am I doing things wrong?