# QueryString is taking first substring and discarding rest post space

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a query string which passes 6 parameters in C# as shown below

```
string url = "Report.aspx?Desc=" + Desc.SelectedValue + "&PON=" + PNumber.Text + "&InsNme=" + ins.ToUpper().ToString() + "&BackTy=" + cb.SelectedValue + "&StartDate=" + txtDate.Text + "&EndDate=" + txtTodate.Text + "&Name=" + nme;
string s = "window.open('" + url + "', 'popup_window', 'width=1500,height=800,left=200,top=150,resizable=yes');";
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "script", s, true);
```

Now, in the above string `InsNme` contains a value of `John Patrice Joanne`. Instead of complete value of `InsNme` `Report.aspx` contains just `John`. How to handle this?

Comment: Need to url encode those spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The spaces in the name are breaking the URL.

If you want to do it yourself, replace spaces with %20.  Otherwise a simple, but not anywhere near "good" technique is:

```
url = "Report.aspx?";
// for each name value pair ...
url += dataLabel + "=" + System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode( dataChunk ) +"&";
```

The utility is preferred as it will take care of other, similar issues such as literal '&' in a name.

Check this answer for better solutions.
[How to build a query string for a URL in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/829080/how-to-build-a-query-string-for-a-url-in-c)

Comment: After i added, `url = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode( url ); string s = "window.open('" + url + "', 'popup_window', 'width=1500,height=800,left=200,top=150,resizable=yes');";
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "script", s, true);` I started getting `HTTP Error 404.11 - Not Found`, why is this?

Comment: @Lara That's very easy to answer yourself: Look at `url` in the debugger. Does it exist or not? But I believe I answered it for you in my comment above.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I am getting error like `The request filtering module is configured to deny a request that contains a double escape sequence.`

Comment: @Lara Look. At. `url`. In. The. Debugger. Look at the actual string you've got there. Do you know how to set a breakpoint and use the debugger?

Comment: Good catch @EdPlunkett  I was answering without thinking.