# Invoke-RestMethod how to build a script foreach

Tags: powershell, rest, url

I'm trying to build a script that has 3 parameters to get the data from an API.

How can I associate the below url with a matrix of combinations?

`Invoke-RestMethod  -Uri "https:xxxxxxxx?parameter1=$parameter1&parameter2=$parameter2&parameter3=$parameter3" -UseDefaultCredentials`

Answer (score 0):

**If your script accepts a *single parameter* that is an open-ended *dictionary* (hashtable) of name-value pairs**:

- Construct a query string from the dictionary's name-value pairs with the help of [`[System.Web.HttpUtility]::ParseQueryString()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString), using the technique shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1877016/45375), and append it to the target URI.

```bash
param(
  [System.Collections.IDictionary] $NamesAndValues
)

$uri = 'https:xxxxxxxx'
if ($NamesAndValues.Count) { # Non-empty dictionary was passed 

  # Create the collection of query-string entries.
  $queryStringEntries = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::ParseQueryString('')
  foreach ($param in $NamesAndValues.GetEnumerator()) {
    $queryStringEntries.Add($param.Key, $param.Value)
  }

  # Convert the entries to a query string and append it to the URI.
  $uri += '?' + $queryStringEntries.ToString()

}

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -UseDefaultCredentials
```

Sample invocation, using a [hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables) literal:

```bash
# Results in the following URI:
#      https:xxxxxxxx?parameter1=foo&parameter2=bar%2Fbaz
# Note: -NamesAndValues is positionally implied as the target parameter.
.\YourScript.ps1 @{ param1='foo'; param2='bar/baz' }
```

---

**If you script has a fixed set of *individual, optional parameters*:**

- The [automatic `$PSBoundParameters` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#psboundparameters) is a dictionary that contains information about what parameters were bound on invocation with what values.
- Thus, the same technique for constructing the query string as above can be used, with `$PSBoundParameters` serving as the input dictionary.

```bash
# Declare 3 optional (non-mandatory) parameters,
# -parameter1, -parameter2, -parameter3
param(
  $parameter1,
  $parameter2,
  $parameter3
)

# Construct the URI based on whatever parameters were bound.
$uri = 'https:xxxxxxxx'
if ($PSBoundParameters.Count) { # At least 1 parameter was bound.

  # Create the collection of query-string entries.
  $queryStringEntries = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::ParseQueryString('')
  foreach ($param in $PSBoundParameters.GetEnumerator()) {
    $queryStringEntries.Add($param.Key, $param.Value)
  }

  # Convert the entries to a query string and append it to the URI.
  $uri += '?' + $queryStringEntries.ToString()

}

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -UseDefaultCredentials
```

Sample invocation:

```bash
# Results in the following URI:
#      https:xxxxxxxx?parameter1=foo&parameter2=bar%2Fbaz
.\YourScript.ps1 -parameter1 'foo' -parameter2 'bar/baz'
```

Answer (score 0):

`("x","y","z"),("p","q","r"),("a","b","c") | ForEach-Object {"https://blah?p1={0}&p2={1}=&p3={2}" -f @($_)}`

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: @mklement0 Sorry, frequent reader but total novice contributor :p Backticks is all I need here, right?

Comment: Single backticks are best used for _inline_ code formatting. For stand-alone, especially multi-line snippets you'll want code _blocks_. The previously linked article contains everything you need to know.

Comment: As for your solution: while it is elegant, its assumptions are at odds with the OP's request to support a "matrix of combinations", and, as it turns out, not even the parameter _names_ can assumed to be static. Aside from that, note that you cannot blindly embed arbitrary string values in a query string - escaping may be needed.

Answer (score -1):

I finally found out the below scheme to create the query. It works good.

```
$data = @()
$data += 'four'
$data = @('Zero','One','Two','Three')
foreach ( $node in $data )
{
    "Item: [$node]"
}
for ( $index = 0; $index -lt $data.count; $index++)
{
    "Item: [{0}]" -f $data[$index]
}
$JoinArray.Add($value)
$JoinArray
```

Comment: It is unclear how this solution relates to what you asked for - where is the conversion to a URL query string, and where are the name-value pairs?. Also, `$JoinArray` and `$value` are never initialized. On a meta note: It is usually better if you continue to work with those that have already provided answers to get to the desired solution.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).