# Reverse function of HttpUtility.ParseQueryString

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, query-string, namevaluecollection

.Net's `System.Web.HttpUtility` class defines [the following function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150046.aspx) to parse a query string into a `NameValueCollection`:

```
public static NameValueCollection ParseQueryString(string query);
```

Is there any function to do the reverse (i.e. to convert a `NameValueCollection` into a query string)?

Comment: Similar Questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/229925/outputing-a-manipulated-querystring-in-c/
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/829080/how-to-build-a-query-string-for-a-url-in-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A NameValueCollection has an automatic ToString() method that will write all your elements out as a querystring automatically.

you don't need to write your own.

```
var querystringCollection = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString("test=value1&test=value2");

var output = querystringCollection.ToString();
```

output = "test=value1&test=value2"

Comment: Incorrect. "System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection" does NOT support this. It's a feature of "System.Web.HttpValueCollection".

Comment: ... and "System.Web.HttpValueCollection" is an internal type.

Comment: Note that this does not handle international characters; it uses HttpUtility.UrlEncodeUnicode internally to escape characters.

Answer (score 26):

`System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection` does **NOT** support this, but a derived internal class `System.Web.HttpValueCollection` **DOES** (by overriding `ToString()`).

Unfortunately (being internal) you cannot instantiate this class directly, but one is returned by `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString()` (and you can call this with `String.Empty`, but not `Null`).

Once you have a `HttpValueCollection`, you can fill it from your original `NameValueCollection` by calling `Add()`, before finally calling `ToString()`.

```
var nameValueCollection = new NameValueCollection {{"a","b"},{"c","d"}};
var httpValueCollection = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(String.Empty);
httpValueCollection.Add(nameValueCollection);
var qs = httpValueCollection.ToString();
```

nameValueCollection.ToString() = "System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection"
httpValueCollection.ToString() = "a=b&c=d"

Answer (score 3):

I found that a combination of `UriBuilder` and `HttpUtility` classes meets my requirements to manipulate query parameters. The `Uri` class on its own is not enough, particularly as its `Query` property is read only.

```
var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder("http://example.com/something?param1=whatever");
var queryParameters = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uriBuilder.Query);
queryParameters.Add("param2", "whatever2");
queryParameters.Add("param3", "whatever2");
uriBuilder.Query = queryParameters.ToString();
var urlString = uriBuilder.Uri.ToString();
```

The above code results in the URL string: http://example.com/something?param1=whatever&param2=whatever2&param3=whatever2

Note that the ToString() goes via a `Uri` property, otherwise the output string would have an explicit port 80 in it.

It's nice to be able to do all this using framework classes and not have to write our own code.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a built in one, but here is an example of how to implement http://blog.leekelleher.com/2008/06/06/how-to-convert-namevaluecollection-to-a-query-string/

Answer (score -1):

Here are 2 very useful functions that I use all the time:

```
    private string GetQueryStringParameterValue(Uri url, string key)
    {
        return HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(url.Query.TrimStart('?'))[key];
    }

    private Uri SetQueryStringParameterValue(Uri url, string key, string value)
    {
        var parameters = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(url.Query.TrimStart('?'));

        parameters[key] = value;

        var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(url) { Query = parameters.ToString() };

        return uriBuilder.Uri;
    }
```